# Else clause on Python while statement

Tags: python, syntax, while-loop, if-statement

I've noticed the following code is legal in Python. My question is why? Is there a specific reason?

```
n = 5
while n != 0:
    print n
    n -= 1
else:
    print "what the..."
```

---

<sub>Many beginners accidentally stumble on this syntax when they try to put an `if`/`else` block inside of a `while` or `for` loop, and don't indent the `else` properly. The solution is to make sure the `else` block lines up with the `if`, assuming that it was your intent to pair them. This question explains *why it didn't cause a syntax error*, and *what the resulting code means.* See also [I'm getting an IndentationError. How do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45621722), for the cases where there *is* a syntax error reported.</sub>

<sub>See also [Why does python use 'else' after for and while loops?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9979970/) for questions about *how to make good use of* the feature.</sub>

Comment: @detly: That's because most people avoid this construct. :) I believe Guido mentioned during the Py3k process that, at the very least, the choice of the word `else` for this use had been a remarkably bad idea, and that they wouldn't be doing any more of these.

Comment: @Nicholas Knight - yeah, tempting though it is, it'd probably be something only I understood on first glance. Any other poor sap would have to go and look at the language spec, or go back in time and post a question here on Sta- heeeeey...

Comment: @detly What would be a better word than else?

Comment: @Baz - Nothing really, I just don't think the binary implication of "else" suits a looping construct very well.

Comment: The idea behind choosing 'else' is that this construct is supposedly often used in conjunction with an 'if X: break' inside the while loop. Since the 'else' clause is executed if we don't break out of the loop, it forms a kinda-sorta 'else' to the 'if'.

Comment: I stumbled upon this a few minutes ago, [this is what I gathered](http://pastebin.com/HHMRpcQw).

Comment: They should rename it `after:`.

Comment: @naught101 - After isn't really appropriate either, because it wouldn't execute if you used "break" or "return" to exit the loop. I always tell people who are struggling to remember the usage, "If you're breaking out of the loop, you have an opportunity to do something right before your break statement. If you're exhausting your collection (in a for loop) or breaking your loop condition (in a while loop), the 'else' clause is your place to wrap up."

Comment: Hard to name, but if I heard correctly, Raymond Hettinger suggested `nobreak:` as a name here (BTW, this also works in `for` loops).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does python use 'else' after for and while loops?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9979970/why-does-python-use-else-after-for-and-while-loops)

Answer (score 483):

The `else` clause is only executed when your `while` condition becomes false.  If you `break` out of the loop, or if an exception is raised, it won't be executed.

One way to think about it is as an if/else construct with respect to the condition:

```
if condition:
    handle_true()
else:
    handle_false()
```

is analogous to the looping construct:

```
while condition:
    handle_true()
else:
    # condition is false now, handle and go on with the rest of the program
    handle_false()
```

An example might be along the lines of:

```
while value < threshold:
    if not process_acceptable_value(value):
        # something went wrong, exit the loop; don't pass go, don't collect 200
        break
    value = update(value)
else:
    # value >= threshold; pass go, collect 200
    handle_threshold_reached()
```

Comment: "The else clause is only executed when your while condition becomes false." The wording here implies that your while state goes from a state of true to false and than the else will be executed. However, if the while is never true, the else clause will still be executed.

Comment: *pseudocode* So correct me if I'm wrong, but this is exactly the same as `while {} something` *except* that the `something` will be skipped if you `break` in the `while` loop.

Comment: Maybe the most precise pseudocode would be: while(True) { if (cond) { handle_true(); } else { handle_false(); break; } }

Comment: the else clause is NOT executed even if the while condition becomes false, if the while loop is finished with 'break'. For example, changing the condition to false before break.

Comment: If `break` executes, then the condition never evaluated to false. (It's possible that the context became such that the condition *would* evaluated to false, if it were reached again, but that's not the same as evaluating to false.)

Answer (score 144):

The `else` clause is executed if you exit a block normally, by hitting the loop condition or falling off the bottom of a try block. It is *not* executed if you `break` or `return` out of a block, or raise an exception. It works for not only while and for loops, but also try blocks.

You typically find it in places where normally you would exit a loop early, and running off the end of the loop is an unexpected/unusual occasion. For example, if you're looping through a list looking for a value:

```
for value in values:
    if value == 5:
        print "Found it!"
        break
else:
    print "Nowhere to be found. :-("
```

Comment: Actually a fairly useful construct for such a thing. Don't know how many times I've put `found_it=False` at the start of a loop, and then do an if check on `found_it` at the end

Comment: This is a better explanation that the one above which says, "The else clause is only executed when your while condition becomes false".  If you while condition becomes false but you call "break" before you loop, the else clause will *not* be called.  It's not enough for the while condition to become false, you also have to execute that condition.

Answer (score 43):

Allow me to **give an example** on *why* to use this `else`-clause. But:

- my point is now better explained in [Leo’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57247169/825924)
- I use a `for`- instead of a `while`-loop, but `else` works similar (executes unless break was encountered)
- there are better ways to do this (e.g. wrapping it into a function or raising an exception)

###### Breaking out of multiple levels of looping

Here is how it works: the outer loop has a break at the end, so it would only be executed once. However, if the inner loop completes (finds no divisor), then it reaches the else statement and the outer break is never reached. This way, a break in the inner loop will break out of both loops, rather than just one.

```
for k in [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 25]:
    for m in range(2, 10):
        if k == m:
            continue
        print 'trying %s %% %s' % (k, m)
        if k % m == 0:
            print 'found a divisor: %d %% %d; breaking out of loop' % (k, m)
            break
    else:
        continue
    print 'breaking another level of loop'
    break
else:
    print 'no divisor could be found!'
```

Answer (score 30):

The else-clause is executed when the while-condition evaluates to false.

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-while-statement):

> The while statement is used for repeated execution as long as an expression is true:
>
> ```
> while_stmt ::=  "while" expression ":" suite
>                 ["else" ":" suite]
> ```
>
> This repeatedly tests the expression and, if it is true, executes the first suite; if the expression is false (which may be the first time it is tested) the suite of the `else` clause, if present, is executed and the loop terminates.
>
> A `break` statement executed in the first suite terminates the loop without executing the `else` clause’s suite. A `continue` statement executed in the first suite skips the rest of the suite and goes back to testing the expression.

Answer (score 25):

The else clause is only executed when the *while-condition* becomes false.

Here are some examples:

**Example 1:** Initially the condition is false, so *else-clause* is executed.

```
i = 99999999

while i < 5:
    print(i)
    i += 1
else:
    print('this')
```

OUTPUT:

```
this
```

**Example 2:** The *while-condition* `i < 5` never became false because `i == 3` breaks the loop, so *else-clause* was not executed.

```
i = 0

while i < 5:
    print(i)
    if i == 3:
        break
    i += 1
else:
    print('this')
```

OUTPUT:

```
0
1
2
3
```

**Example 3:** The *while-condition* `i < 5` became  false when `i` was `5`, so *else-clause* was executed.

```
i = 0

while i < 5:
    print(i)
    i += 1
else:
    print('this')
```

OUTPUT:

```
0
1
2
3
4
this
```

Answer (score 23):

My answer will focus on WHEN we can use while/for-else.

At the first glance, it seems there is no different when using

```
while CONDITION:
    EXPRESSIONS
print 'ELSE'
print 'The next statement'
```

and

```
while CONDITION:
    EXPRESSIONS
else:
    print 'ELSE'
print 'The next statement'
```

Because the `print 'ELSE'` statement seems always executed in both cases (both when the `while` loop finished or not run).

Then, **it's only different when the statement `print 'ELSE'` will not be executed. 
It's when there is a `break`inside the code block under `while`**

```
In [17]: i = 0

In [18]: while i < 5:
    print i
    if i == 2:
        break
    i = i +1
else:
    print 'ELSE'
print 'The next statement'
   ....:
0
1
2
The next statement
```

If differ to:

```
In [19]: i = 0

In [20]: while i < 5:
    print i
    if i == 2:
        break
    i = i +1
print 'ELSE'
print 'The next statement'
   ....:
0
1
2
ELSE
The next statement
```

`return` is not in this category, because it does the same effect for two above cases.

exception raise also does not cause difference, because when it raises, where the next code will be executed is in exception handler (except block), the code in `else` clause or right after the `while` clause will not be executed.

Answer (score 13):

I know this is old question but...

As Raymond Hettinger said, it should be called `while/no_break` instead of `while/else`.
I find it easy to understeand if you look at this snippet.

```
n = 5
while n > 0:
    print n
    n -= 1
    if n == 2:
        break
if n == 0:
    print n
```

Now instead of checking condition after while loop we can swap it with `else` and get rid of that check.

```
n = 5
while n > 0:
    print n
    n -= 1
    if n == 2:
        break
else:  # read it as "no_break"
    print n
```

I always read it as `while/no_break` to understand the code and that syntax makes much more sense to me.

Answer (score 2):

Else is executed if while loop did not break.

I kinda like to think of it with a 'runner' metaphor.

The "else" is like crossing the finish line, irrelevant of whether you started at the beginning or end of the track. "else" is only *not* executed if you break somewhere in between.

```py
runner_at = 0 # or 10 makes no difference, if unlucky_sector is not 0-10
unlucky_sector = 6
while runner_at < 10:
    print("Runner at: ", runner_at)
    if runner_at == unlucky_sector:
        print("Runner fell and broke his foot. Will not reach finish.")
        break
    runner_at += 1
else:
    print("Runner has finished the race!") # Not executed if runner broke his foot.
```

Main use cases is using this breaking out of nested loops or if you want to run some statements only if loop didn't break somewhere (think of breaking being an unusual situation).

For example, the following is a mechanism on how to break out of an inner loop without using variables or try/catch:

```py
for i in [1,2,3]:
    for j in ['a', 'unlucky', 'c']:
        print(i, j)
        if j == 'unlucky':
            break
    else: 
        continue  # Only executed if inner loop didn't break.
    break         # This is only reached if inner loop 'breaked' out since continue didn't run. 

print("Finished")
# 1 a
# 1 b
# Finished
```

Answer (score 2):

```
thing = 'hay'
while thing:
  if thing == 'needle':
    print('I found it!!')  # wrap up for break
    break
  thing = haystack.next()
else:
  print('I did not find it.')  # wrap up for no-break
```

The possibly unfortunately named `else`-clause is your place to wrap up from loop-exhaustion **without break.**

- if there is nothing to do in that case, no `else`-clause is necessary
- you break with `return` or `raise` → the entire code after the call or `try` is your no-break place instead
- instead of `else` you could set a default before `while` (e.g. `found = False`)

  - but it invites bugs related to the handling of the default
  - an `else`-clause saves you from those bugs

If you use a multiple breaks with non-trivial wrap-up, you should use a simple assignment before break, an `else`-clause assignment for no-break, and an `if`-`elif`-`else` or `match`-`case` to *avoid repeating non-trival break handling code.*

Note: everything above also applies to `for thing in haystack:`

Answer (score -1):

The `else:` statement is executed when and only when the while loop no longer meets its condition (in your example, when `n != 0` is false).

So the output would be this:

```
5
4
3
2
1
what the...
```

Comment: I know but this kind of while/else doesn't work in Java. I find it quite interesting when I figured out it works in Python. I was just curious and wanted to know the technical reason.

Comment: @Ivan: It's not so much that it doesn't *work* in Java but that it doesn't *exist* in Java. It could be made to work, if someone cared to add it to the language.

Comment: No, while False: .. else .. still runs the else clause. It's more accurate to say: else is only not ran if loop is broken out of.

Comment: The `else` part is also not ran if there is a `return` or an exception is raised.

Answer (score -1):

Suppose you've to search an element x in a single linked list

```
    def search(self, x):
        position = 1
        p =self.start
        while p is not None:
            if p.info == x:
                print(x, " is at position ", position)
                return True
            position += 1
            p = p.link
        else:
            print(x, "not found in list") 
            return False
```

So if while conditions fails else will execute, hope it helps!

Comment: Omitting the `else:` clause of the `while` statement in this snippet doesn’t change the behavior of the code.

Comment: @BrunoEly this code is a snippet of a single linked list program, so you need a whole code to run it accurately.

Comment: You miss my point.  I'm trying to say an `else:` clause after a `while` block that has _no `break` statement_ is pointless-- it does not alter the behavior of the code.

Comment: Yeah, I got it, IDK how I misinterpreted that time(my bad).
even with a break statement else will not execute though.

Answer (score -2):

The better use of 'while: else:' construction in Python should be if no loop is executed in 'while' then the 'else' statement is executed. The way it works today doesn't make sense because you can use the code below with the same results...

```
n = 5
while n != 0:
    print n
    n -= 1
print "what the..."
```

Comment: No, the difference is that the `else` block will not be executed if you are leaving loop using `break` or `return` keyword. In your example, `print` will be executed also if loop has ended on `break` command.

Comment: You describe how most people wish that the feature worked, not how it actually works!

Answer (score -2):

As far as I know the main reason for adding else to loops in any language is in cases when the iterator is not on in your control. Imagine the iterator is on a server and you just give it a signal to fetch the next 100 records of data. You want the loop to go on as long as the length of the data received is 100. If it is less, you need it to go one more times and then end it. There are many other situations where you have no control over the last iteration. Having the option to add an else in these cases makes everything much easier.

Comment: The only times the `else:` clause doesn’t run is when you break out of the loop, so this example doesn’t call for such a construct.  I.e., whatever code would be inside the `else:` block may doesn’t need an `else:` statement (for this example).