# What is the benefit(s) of having 'else clause' for the while loop in python?

Tags: python, controls

Any code after while loop will execute when the condition in the while loop becomes False. It is the same for the code in the 'else clause' section of while loop in python. So What's the advantage of having 'else' in the while loop?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`else` will not execute if there is a `break` statement in the loop. From the [docs](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-while-statement):

> The `while` statement is used for
>   repeated execution as long as an
>   expression is true:
>
> ```
> while_stmt ::=  "while" expression ":" suite
>                 ["else" ":" suite]
> ```
>
> This repeatedly tests the expression
>   and, if it is true, executes the first
>   suite; if the expression is false
>   (which may be the first time it is
>   tested) the suite of the `else` clause,
>   if present, is executed and the loop
>   terminates.
>
> **A `break` statement executed in the
>   first suite terminates the loop
>   without executing the `else` clause’s
>   suite.** A `continue` statement executed
>   in the first suite skips the rest of
>   the suite and goes back to testing the
>   expression.

(emphasis mine) This also works for `for`loops, by the way. It's not often useful, but usually very elegant when it is.

---

I believe the standard use case is when you are searching through a container to find a value:

```
for element in container:
    if cond(element):
        break
else:
    # no such element
```

Notice also that after the loop, `element` will be defined in the global scope, which is convenient.

---

I found it counterintuitive until I heard a good explanation from some mailing list:

> `else` suites *always* execute when a condition has been evaluated to `False`

So if the condition of a `while` loop is executed and found false, the loop will stop and the `else` suite will run. `break` is different because it exits the loop *without* testing the condition.

Answer (score 1):

The else clauses for the looping constructs was to eliminate flags to distinguish between normal and "abnormal" loop exits. For example, in C you might have:

```
int found = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < BUFSIZ; i++) {
    if(...predicate..) {
       found++;
       break;
    }
}
if(found) {
    // I broke out of the for
} else {
    // the for loop hit BUFSIZ
}
```

Whereas with a loop-else you can eliminate the (somewhat contrived) `found` flag

Comment: The `found` variable is unnecessary even in the C code, you could use `if(i!=BUFSIZ)` instead of `if(found)`.

Comment: Agreed, thus the "contrived" bit.

Answer (score 0):

quoting ars: "The else clause is only executed when your while condition becomes false. If you break out of the loop, or if an exception is raised, it won't be executed."

See [Else clause on Python while statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3295938/else-clause-on-python-while-statement) .

Answer (score 0):

The `else` suite on Python loops is best thought of for the case where the loop is performing a search.  It's where you handle the case where your search was unsuccessful.  (There may be other cases where you might use this, but this is the most common and easily remembered user/case).

The alternative would be to use a sentinel value:

```
sentinel = object()
result = sentinel
for each_item in some_container:
    if matches_some_criteria(each_item):
        result = each_item
        break
if result is sentinel:
    do_something_about_failure()
```