# Else statement executed even if break is triggered in while loop

Tags: python, python-2.7, embedded

I have a while loop which checks for the rising edge of the variable Accessory2. My code is the following:

```
            # Check for rising edge of ACC2
    while (currentTime.Value - StartTime) < TimeOutValue:
        if Accessory2.Value == 1:
            Acc2StartTime = currentTime.Value
            print rttPrefix + "ACC2 output to ON"
            break
        yield None
    else:
        print rttPrefix + "No ACC2 output"
        DynamicFlag.Value = -2
```

However, when the variable Accessory2 goes up, the break condition stops the if statement but the else statement is also executed. Any idea why ?

The output is the following:

```
*RTT:* ACC2 output to ON
*RTT:* No ACC2 output
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you're just executing (or continuing) the while loop multiple times, and the first execution prints your first line and a subsequent execution prints the second.

Comment: That's it ! The condition to execute this while statement was still True after the break. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score -2):

Your else statement is indented at the same level as your while loop, so thus is not inside it.

Comment: It appears that this was intended. The `else` clause of the `while `statement` should not be executed if the loop was broken out of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3295938/else-clause-on-python-while-statement

Comment: The question asked why an else statement would run after breaking out of a loop.  It runs because A) it's not inside the loop and B) because it's not indented at the same level as the if statement above it.

Comment: @James The else statement is *not* supposed to run if the loop was broken out of.

Comment: @JamesScholes, this is an while-associated else, not if-associated. It should not be executed when while loop halted with a break statement.