# Are else statements not compatible with while loops?

Tags: java

I am trying to do a while loop for the health of an enemy so that it keeps asking what spell to use until the enemy's health is less than or equal to zero, but the else statement doesn't seem to be working...

```
while(monster_base_health>0) {
    System.out.println("Would you like to use 1. Fire Blast, 2. Ice Blast, 3. Void Ray? (Just type 1, 2, or 3)");
    int attack;
    attack = input.nextInt();

    if(attack==1) {
        monster_base_health = monster_base_health - mage_fire;
        System.out.println("You used Fire Blast. The Monster now has " + monster_base_health + " health!");
    }
    if(attack==2) {
        monster_base_health = monster_base_health - mage_iceblast;
        System.out.println("You used Ice Blast. The monster has " + monster_base_health + " health!");
    }
    if(attack==3) { 
        monster_base_health = monster_base_health - mage_voidray;
        System.out.println("You used Void Ray. The monster has " + monster_base_health + " health!");
    }   
} else {
    System.out.println("You have defeated the monster!!!");
}
```

Comment: Move the `}` before the `else` at the end of your snippet and change the second and third if to `else if` (or the construct of your language) and it should work.

Comment: @ConcurrentHashMap: That would break the logic of the game.  I don't think the condition in this case relates to the `if` blocks.  Look at the logic being expressed.  That `else` means that the monster is defeated, not that the attack was a different value.

Comment: @David Yeah, you should be right with that. I will take care in my answer.

Comment: Someone is a little too used to Python!

Comment: @AndyG Wow, thanks for this hint! Didn't know about [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3295938/else-clause-on-python-while-statement)!

Answer (score 3):

At first, the answer to the general question: **No,  the `while` loop doesn't have any else-condition.**

As `while` is an iterator that runs multiple times (as long as the condition is true), you should check for `if` and `else` inside your `while` loop (as you did id). You could check for special conditions in a way like this:

```
a = 10
while(a > 0) {
    if(a == 1) {
        echo "one";
    } else if(a == 2) {
        echo "two"
    } else {
        // Catch anything else
        echo "more than two"
    }
    // decrease a by 1
    a = a-1
}
// only when the while condition isn't true any more, the next statement is executed
echo "a is zero!"
```

Note: this isn't meant to be a valid programming language but pseudo-code.

Now to your general logic problem inside your code:

You don't need any else statement. As the `while` is executed until the `monster_base_health` is zero or less, the next statement below will only be printed out once the `while` is left.

```
while(monster_base_health > 0) {
    System.out.println("Would you like to use 1. Fire Blast, 2. Ice Blast, 3. Void Ray? (Just type 1, 2, or 3)");
    int attack;
    attack = input.nextInt();

    if(attack == 1) {
        monster_base_health = monster_base_health - mage_fire;
        System.out.println("You used Fire Blast. The Monster now has " + monster_base_health + " health!");
    }
    if(attack == 2) {
        monster_base_health = monster_base_health - mage_iceblast;
        System.out.println("You used Ice Blast. The monster has " + monster_base_health + " health!");
    }
    if(attack == 3) {   
        monster_base_health = monster_base_health - mage_voidray;
        System.out.println("You used Void Ray. The monster has " + monster_base_health + " health!");
    }
}

System.out.println("You have defeated the monster!!!");
```

Comment: `"and it should work"` - It will *compile*, yes.  But the logic will be fundamentally changed and it will no longer "work" at runtime.

Comment: @David See my edit now. I haven't thought about the logic first, but now it should fit.

Comment: +1: @NathanSpangenberg here is the simplest/best explanation. All the answers are valid though, make sure you read and understand what everybody is saying.

Answer (score 1):

What do you expect this `else` statement to do?

`else` blocks have nothing to do with `while` blocks.  They're related to `if` blocks.  The semantic concept is:

```
if (some condition is true)
    do something
else (the condition was not true)
    do something else
```

What you're trying to do is this:

```
while (some condition is true)
    do something
else (the condition was not true)
    do something else
```

Which doesn't really make a lot of sense.  The loop doesn't care if the condition is true or not, it just executes while that condition is true.  (Which may be anywhere from zero to infinite executions of the loop.)

Think of it this way... If the loop continues while the condition is true, then as soon as the loop is done the condition is *by definition* no longer true.  So anything after the loop means "the condition is not true".  So you can just do this:

```
while (the condition is true)
    do something
do the next thing
```

No `else` block required.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers show you how you should use `if` statements and how `if` and `else` relate to each other.

Here is another way of achieving what you want. You can use a `switch` statement instead of `if/else` to make your code a little cleaner. 
Mind you, since your loop condition tests whether `monster_base_health` is 0, once you are outside of the loop it means that `monster_base_health` reached 0 so you can just print your statement there.

```
    while (monster_base_health > 0) {
        System.out
                .println("Would you like to use 1. Fire Blast, 2. Ice Blast, 3. Void Ray? (Just type 1, 2, or 3)");
        int attack = input.nextInt();
        switch (attack) {
        case 1:
            monster_base_health = monster_base_health - mage_fire;
            System.out.println("You used Fire Blast. The Monster now has "
                    + monster_base_health + " health!");
            break;
        case 2:
            monster_base_health = monster_base_health - mage_iceblast;
            System.out.println("You used Ice Blast. The monster has "
                    + monster_base_health + " health!");
            break;
        case 3:
            monster_base_health = monster_base_health - mage_voidray;
            System.out.println("You used Void Ray. The monster has "
                    + monster_base_health + " health!");
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Please use a valid attack");
            break;

        }
    }
    System.out.println("You have defeated the monster!!!");
```

**NOTE 1**: Use the `default` case to cover all options that are considered invalid based on your program logic. This means if the user inputs any attack value other than 1, 2 or 3, the `default` case will be executed telling them to use a valid attack.

**NOTE 2**: Don't forget to `break` out of each `case`. If you don't, the next `case` will be executed as well not matter if its condition happened. And then the next of that statement, and then next of that next statement and so on until a `break` is encountered or the `}` for the end of the `switch` block.

Answer (score 0):

Else blocks are part of the if-else conditionals, they are ***not*** part of conditional looping structures.

Did you mean for the else to be part of an if block within the while loop? If so, simply move the else block to be in tandem with whichever if block it should be paired with.

Here is an example based on your code of what I'm talking about:

```
while(monster_base_health>0)
{
    System.out.println("Would you like to use 1. Fire Blast, 2. Ice Blast, 3. Void Ray? (Just type 1, 2, or 3)");
    int attack;
    attack = input.nextInt();

    if(attack==1)
    {
        monster_base_health = monster_base_health - mage_fire;
        System.out.println("You used Fire Blast. The Monster now has " + monster_base_health + " health!");
    } else if(attack==2)
    {
        monster_base_health = monster_base_health - mage_iceblast;
        System.out.println("You used Ice Blast. The monster has " + monster_base_health + " health!");
    } else if(attack==3)
    {   
        monster_base_health = monster_base_health - mage_voidray;
        System.out.println("You used Void Ray. The monster has " + monster_base_health + " health!");
    }   

} // end while
System.out.println("You have defeated the monster!!!");
```

Comment: I don't think the condition in this case relates to the `if` blocks.  Look at the logic being expressed.  That `else` means that the monster is defeated, not that the attack was a different value.

Comment: @David, you are correct, I've modified the while loop to cover what we think he is trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You may be getting in to the else section when the input is any other value except 3 (for 1,2, 4,5,....).

You have to use **else if** instead of **plain if**.

```
if(xx==1){

}else if(xx==2){

}else if(xx==3){

}else{

}
```

**Theres nothing to deal with while loop**

or you may be trying something like this

```
while(h>0){
   if(xx==1){
      h-=1;
   }else if(xx==2){
      h-=2;
   }else if(xx==3){
      h-=3;
   }else{
      // wrong input- do nothing
   }
}   // end of while  

   // reached here means h is 0 or less
display -> you are dead   //dead code here
```

Comment: I don't think the condition in this case relates to the `if` blocks.  Look at the logic being expressed.  That `else` means that the monster is defeated, not that the attack was a different value.

Comment: else means you have inserted something else. not 1 or 2 or 3. The if statement is checking the input number, not the health level.

Your while will continue till you have more health remaining. While fail means your health is 0 or less. You are checking health in while condition not in if condition

Comment: My point is that there's no need for an `else` in the conditionals because the code has no such logical case.  (One can argue that it *might* someday and should be designed accordingly, though in that case polymorphism can cleanly replace this conditional.  But that's not the question being asked.)  Also, your last `if` statement is entirely superfluous.  Once the loop is exited, `h <= 0` *must* be true *every time*.  All you're testing with that conditional is whether or not the computer can do math.  If it can't, the application won't be able to handle that anyway.

Comment: Yes. correct. Its useless an else at the bottom. edited my code. Thanks. :D

Answer (score 0):

No need for the else.  When it doesn't meet the loop condition it will break out of the loop just place your code you would have placed in the else after the loop.