# WHILE repeats before ELSE is evaluated

Tags: java

I've nested an IF ELSE statement inside a WHILE statement, but am confused as to why the WHILE is interpreted before the ELSE (when the IF fails). A user is asked to enter a number from 1-10 (inclusive). If the number is inside that range, the program ends. If it's outside of that range, I want to display an error and then prompt them to again enter a number.

It works well if I put the "prompt" before the WHILE, but then I have to put it *again* inside the ELSE statement for it to show up again. I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25793238/are-else-statements-not-compatible-with-while-loops), but it didn't appear to answer the issue I'm running into. I'm admittedly a Java novice, so I apologize if I'm missing some fundamental aspect of Java.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Rangecheck {
private static int userNumber;   //Number input by user
private static boolean numberOK = false; //Final check if number is valid
//String that will be reused in the DO statement
private static String enterNumber = "Please enter a number from 1 to 10: ";

public static void main(String[] args) {
//Print string
while(!numberOK) // Repeat until the number is OK
{ System.out.println(enterNumber);
 Scanner input_UserNumber = new Scanner(System.in); //input integer
 userNumber = input_UserNumber.nextInt();

 if (10>= userNumber && userNumber >= 1) //Check if 10>=input>=1
 {
     /*
     ** If number was valid, congratulate the user and mark numberOK true
     */
     System.out.println("Good job! The number you entered is "+userNumber+".");
      numberOK = true; // Congratulate user / exit loop if successful
}
 else ; //if (10 < userNumber && userNumber < 1)
 {
      System.err.println("The number entered was not between 1 and 10!");
      System.err.print(enterNumber); // Error; user retries until successful
            }

}

}
}
```

I'd expect the `System.err.println()` to be evaluated in the `else` statement and then the `while`to be evaluated, so that this gets returned:

```
    The number entered was not between 1 and 10!    
    Please enter a number between 1 and 10:
```

I've sort of worked around this by putting enterNumber just before `while`, then putting a second 
`println` in the `else` statement immediately following the error. It returns what I expect, but I believe I'm fundamentally misunderstanding something.

Comment: Well the else is evaluated? How else do you explain that `"The number entered was not between 1 and 10!"` is printed?

Comment: Try putting a breakpoint at the beginning of your application, and stepping over each line to help you understand the order of execution.

Comment: Seems like a problem when using your `Scanner`. Please provide the complete code of your application to check where the error lies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's suppose you have the following code:

```
while (whileCondition) {
    //Inside while, before if
    if (ifCondition) {
        //Inside if
    } else {
        //Inside else
    }
}
```

This cycle will execute repeatedly, until the `whileCondition` becomes `false`. Whenever the `ifCondition` is `true`, the operations inside `if` will be executed, otherwise the operations inside `else` will be executed.

Back to your problem:

Your line of

```
System.out.println(enterNumber);
```

is at the start of the `while`. So before the code even gets to your `if`, the content of `enterNumber` is displayed on the console. Later, your `if` is evaluated and if you enter, let's say 22, the condition given to the `if` will be `false` and the content of the `else` block will be evaluated.

Comment: If I understand, this answer states that the code should work as expected. Again, like I posted in my comment, this seems like an error when using `Scanner`, probably due to reading without using `nextLine` or something similar, but we cannot be sure since OP don't post more of the code.

Answer (score 0):

The `else` statement is repeated before the `while` statement. There can however sometimes be a problem with `Stream`s. A `Stream` does not necessarily print the data immediately. Especially in the case one uses two different streams, the order of printing the output data can be interleaved.

You can use:

```
System.err.flush();
```

to ensure the data is written to the console first.

Comment: Actually better is to not print simple text messages to stderr but rather just use stdout.

Comment: @nmore: The standard in Linux is - as far as I know - to handle all user interaction on `stderr`, `stdout` is only used to "print something semantical". For instance if one runs an interactive shell, the `~>`,etc. should be printed at `sterr`.

Comment: Thanks @CommuSoft. Adding that immediately following my `err.println()` seemed to help, but displays the error regardless of whether the number fit the range. I found that if I use a `System.out.println()` instead of `System.err.println()`, it works properly even without the flush.

I had no idea how `Stream`s came into play.

Answer (score 0):

Add this statement in else body:

```
numberOk=false;
```