# Dark corners of python loops/keywords. Style advice

Tags: python, loops, keyword

Learning python, found this code snippet. It reads text from stdin and prints "Done" when it finishes. I've never seen an `else` for a `while` loop anywhere else in any other language. The comments on the site where I found this said this was a pythonic way to do similar to a `finally` but for a while loop.

```
import sys
while True:
    line = sys.stdin.readline()
    if not line:
        break
else:
    print("Done");
```

The question is, is this pythonic? The place I work has a pretty strict pep-8 compliance policy, so I need to know if this is okay.

Comment: I don't think while-else works that way. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3295938/else-clause-on-python-while-statement

Comment: Well, using unnecessary parens like `while(True)` isn't Pythonic. If you really want to know about using Pythonic style, you may want to consider running a checker like [`pep8`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pep8) to catch all the simple stuff like that, so people can look for the higher-level issues without being distracted.

Comment: Another side note: You almost never need/want to loop over `readline`; just use the file as an iterator. That gives you exactly the behavior you're trying to get with the `while` loop, but without the confusion, and with one line instead of 4-5 lines.

Answer (score 6):

The basic idea of using `while`/`else` is certainly Pythonic—it wouldn't be in the language otherwise.

However, there are two bugs in your code that each mean that your `else` code never runs. It's probably not Pythonic to include code that never executes and is only there to mislead the reader. :) More importantly, it's probably not what you wanted.

---

First, there's no way for you to ever exit the loop (except by exception). `readline` returns an empty string at EOF, so that's probably what you want to check for:

```
while True:
    line = sys.stdin.readline()
    if line:
        print(line)
    else:
        break
else:
    print("Done")
```

But next, I'm not sure `while`/`else` does what you think it does. I think you're expecting it to run the `else` however you exit the loop. But as [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-while-statement) explain:

> A `break` statement executed in the first suite terminates the loop without executing the `else` clause’s suite.

In other words, the `else` part only runs if you exit *normally*, by the condition becoming false. Obviously `while True` never becomes false.

And that's the whole point: sometimes you need to distinguish between the loop finishing normally vs. exiting with an `if something: break`; that's when you use `else:`. If you want to do the same thing either way, just do it:

```
while True:
    line = sys.stdin.readline()
    if line:
        print(line)
    else:
        break
print("Done")
```

---

If you wanted something "similar to a `finally`" because you may have exceptions, the answer is simple: use a `finally`:

```
try:
    while True:
        line = sys.stdin.readline()
        if line:
            print(line)
        else:
            break
finally:
    print("Done")
```

---

As a side note, looping over `readline` with a `while` and `break` is almost never necessary; a file-like object like `sys.stdin` is an iterable of lines, the same lines that `readline` will return, so you can just do:

```
for line in sys.stdin:
    print(line)
print("Done")
```

---

As a side note, it's generally *not* considered Pythonic to use unnecessary parentheses and semicolons in your code—especially when it makes your code look misleadingly like C or Java or something. While [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) is only meant as a standard for the Python stdlib, many people use it as a guide for their own Python software, and it's a good idea to follow its recommendations unless you have a good reason not to. You can use tools like [`pep8`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pep8) to check whether you're following the guidelines. This only catches the simple stuff, like your `while(True):` instead of `while True` and `print("Done");` instead of `print("Done")`, but violating that simple stuff distracts readers from noticing the possible higher-level violations that you're asking about.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, this is a pythonic way to accomplish the goal of your code snippet.  It is known as the else-for-last-iteration-of-loop (EFLIOL) idiom.

Comment: Yep—and the `while` and `for` statements wouldn't _have_ an `else` if it were never Pythonic to use them, would they? :)

Comment: Google returns zero results for "else-for-last-iteration-of-loop". Got a citation? (or is this a joke going over my head?)

Comment: The problem with this answer, is that the loop in the OP's question is infinite, and contains no `break` statement.  So `else` will **never** be reached.  Although in general, I agree (for the reasons listed in the link in Kevin's comment).