# Is there a use of break statement in python?

Tags: python

Is there a use of break statement in python? I noticed that we can end the while loop with another faster ways.

As an example we can say:

```
name=""
while name!="Mahmoud": 
    print('Please type your name.')
    name = input()
print('Thank you!')
```

instead of:

```
while True:
    print('Please type your name.')
    name = input()
    if name == 'Mahmoud':  
        break
print('Thank you!')
```

and what is the meaning of `while True`?

Comment: You should probably take a look at the [official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial).

Comment: While true means: while true == true...which it always does, so it is a way of creating an infinite loop. A break has many many uses...to many examples.

Comment: Shorter isn't always better.  There are plenty of other uses of `break` than polling for input.  Don't assume just because it doesn't look good to you in one case that it serves no purpose.

Comment: Why do you criticize me i just wanted to know what is its other uses? i didn't say it's useless :)

Comment: I note that those two code blocks above are not [entirely equivalent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3295938/else-clause-on-python-while-statement), because Python's while loop can have an else clause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`break` is useful if you want to end the loop part-way through.

```
while True:
  print('Please type your name.')
    name = input()
    if name == 'Mahmoud':
      break
    print('Please try again')
  print('Thank you!')
```

If you do this with `while name != 'Mahmoud':`, it will print `Please try again` at the end, even though you typed `Mahmoud`.

`while True:` means to loop forever (or until something inside the loop breaks you out), since the looping condition can never become false.