# #PYTHON - Else statements with Loop?

Tags: python, loops, if-statement

I am a C guy. These days i am learning python for my latest project requirement.
Now my question is : What is the significance of Else statements with Loops[While, For..]. Do we really need them ??

Comment: See this http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201110/forelse.html and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9979970/why-does-python-use-else-after-for-and-while-loops

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Editted from [Else clause on Python while statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3295938/else-clause-on-python-while-statement) :

> The `else` clause is only executed when your `[Loop]`'s condition becomes false.  If you `break` out of the loop, or if an exception is raised, it won't be executed.

In other words, its just a way to check if the loop was run without any problems, and everything that was suppoused to be done is done. If you had to `break` or `throw` an exception in the middle, then the else statement won't execute since the loop didn't finish "properly".

**EDIT**: an example from a linked thread explains this well. The else statement checks if the loop was executted **completely** - and if it was not broken out of and there wasn't an exception raised, you can do a certain action. for example:

```
...

for i in mylist:
    if i == theflag:
        break
    process(i)
else:
    raise ValueError("List argument missing terminal flag.)

...
```

Notice, that's just for syntax. Of course you can do it without the `for-else` statement, like so:

```
...

flagfound = False
for i in mylist:
    if i == the flag:
        flagfound = True
        break
    process(i)

if not flagfound:
    raise ValueError("List argument missing terminal flag.)

...
```

but *syntax-wise*, the first way often looks better.

Comment: Ok ..Would you please give me an example when we really need to use else statement  ?

Comment: @SJ26 editted, take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Python has the ability to execute code when a `for` loop has exhausted its list or when a `while` loop becomes false.

It's actually quite nice if you want to do special handling if the loop was "unsuccessful". For example, searching a list for a number:

```
for testVal in listOfVals:
    if lookingFor == testVal:
        print("Found one")
else:
    print("Not in the list")
```

With other languages (such as C), it's common to keep a `found` boolean variable to indicate that it was found, then check that variable after the loop, something like:

```
int found = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    if (lookingFor == listOfVals[i]) {
        puts ("Found one")
        found = 1;
    }
}
if (!found) {
    puts ("Not in the list")
}
```

There are probably other ways you could acheive the same end in C but the Python method seems more natural to me.