# Python: Forming overlapping matrix of 3*3 using 9*9 matrix

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to create a neighborhood of pixel by using pixel matrix. The pixel matrix is the matrix of pixels in a 1 band image. Now I have to form matrix of 3*3 keeping each element of 9*9 matrix at center and have a neighbor for each element. Thus the element at (0,0) position will have neighboring elements as

```
[[0 0 0],
 [0 2 3],
 [0 3 4]]
```

Same case will happen to all elements in the first and last row and column. [Attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8N0oy.jpg) can help understanding better.

So the resultant matrix will have the size of 81*81. It is not necessary to save the small matrix in the form of matrix.

I have tried below,

```
n = size[0]
z= 3
x=y=0
m =0

while all( [x<0, y<0, x>=n, y>=n]):
    continue
else:
    for i in range(0, n):
        arcpy.AddMessage("Hello" ) 
        for x in range(m,m+3):
            temp_matrix = [ [ 0 for i in range(3) ] for j in range(3) ]
            for y in range(m,m+3):
                temp_matrix[x][y] = arr_Pixels[x][y]
                m+=1
            y+=1

            temp_List.append(temp_matrix)
```

But I am getting `error: list assignment out of index.`  Also it looks too lengthy and confusing. I understood the error is occurring because, there is no increment in the array temp_matrix length.

Is there any better way to implement the matrix in image? Smaller matrices can be saved into list rather than matrix. Please help me.

**Update #2**

```
n = size[0]
new_matrix = [] 
for i in range(0,n):
    for j in range(0,n):
        temp_mat = [ [ 0 for k in range(3) ] for l in range(3) ]
        for k in range(i-1, i+2):
            for l in range(j-1,j+2):
                if any([k<0, l<0, k>n-1, l>n-1]):
                    temp_mat[k][l] = 0
                else:
                    temp_mat[k][l] = arr_Pixels[k][l]

        new_matrix.append(temp_mat)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found better way of doing it by padding the whole matrix by zero. Thus it resolves the negative indexing problems.
matrix can be padded as

```
    pixels = np.pad(arr_Pixels, (1,1), mode='constant', constant_values=(0, 0))
```

It adds rows and columns of zeros along the axes.

Answer (score 0):

I think one issue is your use of while/else. The code in `else` only executes after the while condition is true and the `while` will not repeat again. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3295938/else-clause-on-python-while-statement) might be helpful.

Thus, once it enters `else`, it will never check again that `x<=n` and `y<=n`, meaning that x and y can increase beyond n, which I assume is the length of `arr_Pixels`.

One better way to do it would be to create two nested for loops that increment from 0 to n and create the temp neighborhood matrices and add them to the 9x9 matrix. Here is an rough outline for that:

```
new_matrix = [] //future 9x9 matrix
for i in range(0, n):
    for j in range(0, n):
         // create a neighborhood matrix going around (i, j) 
         // add temp matrix to new_matrix
```

This method would avoid having to check that the indexes you are accessing are less than `n` because it assures that `i` and `j` will always be less than `n-3`.

Comment: can you please elaborate this part
// create temp matrix going from (i, j) to (i+3, j+3) of arr_Pixels                I tried this                                                                                     n = size[0]
new_matrix = [] 
    for i in range(0, n-3):
        for j in range(0, n-3):
#             create temp matrix going from (i, j) to (i+3, j+3) of arr_Pixels
            temp_matrix = []
            for i,j in range(i+3,j+3):
                temp_matrix[i][j] = arr_Pixels[i][j]
            
            new_matrix.append(temp_matrix)    , but it looks incorrect. @s.py

Comment: I don't how to add indented comments. please check. @s.py

Comment: If the approach with n-3 is followed, it will not create the matrix for the last column element as well as first. Even I need first element to be considered in the center. Like from image, for first element 2, I should get |0 0 0|,|0 2 3|,|0 3 4|. @s.py

Comment: Looking over this, it looks like it should be from  (i, j) to (i+2, j+2) instead. I edited my answer to reflect that.

Comment: I'm not totally sure I understand your 3rd comment? I don't see a matrix of |0 0 0|,|0 2 3|,|0 3 4| in your image. Where should that go?

Comment: But yes, your first comment is approximately what I am thinking, if you use +2 instead of +3 instead so there will be 3 total elements (rather than 4)

Comment: Referring to 3rd comment: Yes there are no zeros. I will explain. I am trying to create a neighborhood of pixel by using pixel matrix. The pixel matrix is the matrix of pixels in a 1 band image. Now I have to form matrix of 3*3 keeping each element of 9*9 matrix at center and have a neighbor for each element. Thus the element at (0,0) position will have neighboring elements as |0 0 0|,|0 2 3|,|0 3 4|. I cannot draw a proper matrix here. Same case will happen to all elements in the first and last row and column. In the image, I started from position (2,2). It was my mistake.@s.py

Comment: But I need to start from(0,0). I also tried implementing your logic, but since I have to form 3*3 matrix and loops run for the size of big matrix which 9*9, its not working. Any help would really be appreciated. @s.py

Comment: I think you would use a logic similar to the logic in my answer, but go all the way up to `n` instead of `n-3`.  The neighbors of an element at `(i, j)` of a matrix `mat` are `mat[i-1][j]`, `mat[i-1][j-1]`, `mat[i][j-1]`, etc, all around the circle, unless i or j are 0 or n, in which case you substitute 0s. Does that help? Can you update your question to reflect what you have explained to me?

Comment: I have updated the question. I still have a confusion to limit the small matrix to 3*3, as the loop run for n times. can you help me with that. here is algo i changes, please suggest me the changes.@s.py

Comment: for i in range(0,n):
     for j in range(0,n):

Comment: I am not able to put the logic for circle of neighbor i.e. mat[i-1][j], mat[i-1][j-1], mat[i][j-1] limiting it to 3*3 matrix. Kindly help. @s.py
for i in range(0,n):
     for j in range(0,n):
  if(i<0,j<0, i>n-1, j>n-1):
   temp[i][j] = 0
  else:
   temp[i][j] = arr_Pixels[i-1][j-1]

Comment: Please check above comment. @s.py

Comment: i and j will never be <0 or >n-1. Try `i<0,j<0, i>n-1, j>n-1`

Comment: Yes, I have added the same condition in above algo too. in if(i<0,j<0, i>n-1, j>n-1), but I am stuck at point where I have to form 3* 3. Since the i & j loops for 9 times, I am not able to form a 3*3 matrix. @s.py

Comment: I have added an update to question. please see Update #2. I believe the logic should work, but I am getting an error IndexError: list assignment index out of range. I understood why is it happening as in temp_mat there is no negative index. but I need help resolving error, how do I save the contents in temp_mat. @s.py

Comment: Please look into updated code Update#2 in the question. @s.py