# basic Python if statements not loading

Tags: python

```
print ("Welcome teaacher")  
while True:
   Class = input("Which class (1, 2 or 3) would you like to look at?")
    if Class.lower() not in ('1', '2', '3'):
    print("Not an appropriate choice.")
else:
    break
while True:
    print("Which method would you like to view by?")
    Method = input("Type '1' for average, '2' for highest score or '3' for alphabetical")
    if Class.lower() not in ('1', '2', '3'):
        print("Not an appropriate choice.")
else:
    break
if Method == 1:
    print("You have chosen Class" +Class+ " average")
if Method == 2:
    print("You have chosen Class" +Class+ " highest score")
if Method == 3:
    print("You have chosen Class" +Class+ " alphabetical")
```

I'm trying to get the code to tell me what I've selected but it doesn't recognise the if statements at the end and doesn't print anything at all.

Any help would be great
thanks :)

Comment: Fix your indentation please and provide a better [mcve].

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Else clause on Python while statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3295938/else-clause-on-python-while-statement)

Comment: The duplicate points out that it will *never* break on the `while True` lines (it will never reach a False state). Perhaps you meant to pair the `else` with the `if`s here?

Comment: thank you that helped a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Proper indentation is a fundamental part of Python. The way you've written your question, the `else` statement is applying to the `while` loops (which is a completely valid thing) and not to the `if` statements within the loops. Also, the final `if` statement should use `elif`, which is the Python abbreviation for `else if`.

Here's what it should look like:

```
print ("Welcome teacher")  
while True:
    Class = input("Which class (1, 2 or 3) would you like to look at?")
    if Class.lower() not in ('1', '2', '3'):
        print("Not an appropriate choice.")
    else:
        break

while True:
    print("Which method would you like to view by?")
    Method = input("Type '1' for average, '2' for highest score or '3' for alphabetical")
    if Class.lower() not in ('1', '2', '3'):
        print("Not an appropriate choice.")
    else:
        break

if Method == '1':
    print("You have chosen Class" + Class + " average")
elif Method == '2':
    print("You have chosen Class" + Class + " highest score")
elif Method == '3':
    print("You have chosen Class" + Class + " alphabetical")
```

Comment: it still doesn't recognise the if statements at the bottom with all the changes

Comment: I forgot that your input is a string, so that check on method should be for '1', '2' or '3'. I'll edit the answer with the updates.

Comment: thank you I was stuck for too long on this simple mistake