# Else-statement after while-statement, and string comparison with a list of strings?

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop, conditional-statements

I'm attempting to create a small test script that appends something to a note. Contained below is the main function that I will execute in the script. The problem seems to be that I can't get the `else` block to run when the `while` block evaluates to false (that is to say, when it evaluates to anything that isn't one of those four options), the `while` block just continues in an infinite loop. I've also attempted to insert a `break` into the while loop but this terminates the script after the `while` loop has executed.

How do I move from the `while` to the `else` block when it evaluates to false? And why doesn't the current way I do things work as I would like it to? Thanks.

```
def start():
    q01 = input("What is the subject of your note?\n")
    q02 = input("Are you certain that the subject of your note is " + q01 + "?\n")
    while q02 == 'No' or 'no' or 'NO' or 'n':
       q01 = input("So, what is the subject of your note?\n")
       q02 = input("Are you certain now that the subject of your note is " + q01 + "?\n")
    else:
       q03 = Enter("Enter the content of your note")
```

Comment: Your use of `while`/`else` should work once the `while` condition is fixed according to the accepted answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your culprit is the while loop condition:

```
while q02 == 'No' or 'no' or 'NO' or 'n':
```

This is equivalent to:

```
while (q02 == 'No') or 'no' or 'NO' or 'n':
```

As `'no'`, `'NO'` and `'n'` are all non-empty strings they evaluate to `True` and so your condition evaluates to:

```
while (q02 == 'No') or True or True or True:
```

which is clearly always `True`.

To fix this you need to adjust the condition to:

```
while q02 == 'No' or q02 == 'no' or q02 == 'NO' or q02 == 'n':
```

Although to be more pythonic you could instead make this:

```
while q02 in ['No','no','NO','n']:
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the guard condition on the `while` block is always `True`!

```
>>> q02 = 'y'
>>> q02 == 'No' or 'no'
'no'
```

The `or` operator is interesting.  It evaluates it's left operand and if it is "truthy" then the left operand is the result of the operation; otherwise, it evaluates it's right operand.  In your case, the left operand is a boolean value (the result of `q02 == 'No'`) and the right operand is a non-empty string.  The non-empty string is "truthy" so that is the result.

IOW, `q02 == 'No' or 'no' or 'NO' or 'n'` evaluates to `True` if and only if `q02` is `'No'`.  Otherwise it evaluates to the string `'no'` which is "truthy" as far as the `while` loop is concerned.

```
>>> q02 = 'y'
>>> q02 == 'No' or 'no' or 'NO' or 'n'
'no'
>>> bool(q02 == 'No' or 'no' or 'NO' or 'n')
True
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this statement

```
while q02 == 'No' or 'no' or 'NO' or 'n':
```

to

```
while q02 == 'No' or q02 == 'no' or q02 == 'NO' or q02 == 'n':
```

One more *elegant* way of doing it:

```
def startMe():
    q01 = input("What is the subject of your note?\n")
    q02 = input("Are you certain that the subject of your note is " + q01 + "?\n")
    negList = ['No', 'no', 'NO', 'nO', 'n', 'N']  # <<< Easily modifiable list.

    while any(q02 in s for s in negList):  
       q01 = input("So, what is the subject of your note?\n")
       q02 = input("Are you certain that the subject of your note is " + q01 + "?\n")
    break:
       q03 = input("Enter the content of your note")
```

Comment: Could you provide an explanation of why my method does not work?

Comment: `else` without `if` is destined to fail.

Comment: Could you test this code as I still seem to be stuck in a while loop when I call the function

Comment: Your script misses an essential component of mine. I want the `q01` and `q02` input variables to loop until I've decided that yes, I am certain that the subject of the note is `[x]`. Your script only runs that `if` block once. This is why I used the `while` loop and not the `if` statement. Thank you for your help however, the negList is a nice addition.

Comment: -1. (1) `else` **can** be [combined with `while`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3295938/else-clause-on-python-while-statement). (2) `while q02 == 'No' or 'no' …` is **not wrong syntax**, it just doesn't do what the asker expected.

Comment: Thanks for pointing. But I still don't understand when to use `while q02 == 'No' or 'no'`.

Comment: It makes not much sense to use it, but it's not illegal.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic and code is correct except 1 syntax.
Use 
`while q02 == 'No' or q02 == 'no' or q02 == 'NO' or q02 == 'n':` 
insted of `while q02 == 'No' or 'no' or 'NO' or 'n':`

You can try:

```
def start():
    q01 = input("What is the subject of your note?\n")
    q02 = input("Are you certain that the subject of your note is " + q01 + "?\n")
    while q02 == 'No' or q02 == 'no' or q02 == 'NO' or q02 == 'n':
       q01 = input("So, what is the subject of your note?\n")
       q02 = input("Are you certain now that the subject of your note is " + q01 + "?\n")
    else:
       q03 = input("Enter the content of your note")
start()
```

Comment: Thank you, this works but why is this the case? I did not receive any syntax errors when I did it my way, so why does this method result in activating the else block?