# How to check the same "if condition" twice in python?

Tags: python-3.x

```
if condition: #this statement
    print("if execution") #if statements
else:
    print("if execution")
```

if condition check first time and then it's statements executed. Then again it check if condition second time.

In general it's not possible as on the basis of if condition either if statements or else statements  executes. As if condition is checked once only.

**I can do this in C++ with label and goto.**

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std; 
int main() {
    int cond = 1;

    // if with label l1
    l1: if(cond) { // ...to here
        cout << "inside if";
        cond = 0;
        goto l1; //this switching statement control...
    }

    //else
    else {
        cout << "\ninside else";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Check this: [Check c++ example](https://code.sololearn.com/cUmT8hA18l34/#cpp)

**Some people in comment section are confusing switch with 'switch' keyword in programming language.**

**{switch please! not switch keyword}**

**switch statement controls mean moving control of one statement to another statement.**

Comment: Either I have gone stupid or What ever you ask does not make much sense

Comment: You could put the if below each other twice? Or just put everything in the first if block?

Comment: Is there any way to switch statement controls?

Comment: If you want to check twice put it in a method and call that method and see the condition statement is true or false.

Comment: I agree it is hard/impossible to determine exactly what you are asked no, but my guess would be that you could just repeat the `if condition` test in place of the `else` in your example. Or are you asking if python has a `switch` or `case` statement?

Comment: What you describe in C++ looks like it should have been a `while` loop. This is possible in Python, it even supports an `else` clause (which I don't know whether C++ has an equivalent for). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3295938/else-clause-on-python-while-statement

Comment: while loop where??

Comment: and please! I know python,  and else and while loop.

Comment: switch {please! not switch keyword } statement controls mean moving control of one statement to another statement.

Comment: Maybe you're looking for the [`while... else`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3295938/else-clause-on-python-while-statement) construct in python?

Comment: Check this: [Check python example](https://ideone.com/SphX3o)

Comment: thank mkrieger1, is there any way use only 'if' and 'else' keyword.

Comment: Yes, you can use `if` instead of `while`, but then it won't do what you want.

Comment: I know mkrieger1, this why I am asking.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are talking about the `elif` statement.
Have a look [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html)

```
if condition1:
    print('condition1 True')
elif condition2:
    print('condition1 False, condition2 True')
elif condition3:
    print('condition1 and condition2 are False, condition3 True')
else:
    print('none of the conditions are True')
```

If that is not answering your question, please update and clarify your original post/question.