# time.sleep function within while loop keeps crashing program, solution or alternative method?

Tags: python, time, crash, sleep, turtle-graphics

I am trying to make a space invaders game using turtle, and in order to move the bullet up the screen I am trying to update the y coordinate of the bullet every 0.5 seconds. I tried to do this with a while loop and the time.sleep() function, but everytime I try to fire a bullet, the program crashes. Is there any way I can stop it from doing this? Or why is it not working? Is there an equally effective method that will not crash my program?

```
import turtle
import time

userx = 0

x = 0
y = -300

enemies = [(300,50, "left"), (400,50, "left"), (350, -50, "right")]

bullets = []

gameover = False

def frame():
    pass
    ship = turtle.Turtle()
    ship.pu()
    ship.ht()
    ship.setpos(userx, -300)
    ship.pd()
    ship.circle(5)

    bullet = turtle.Turtle()
    bullet.pu()
    bullet.ht()
    bullet.setpos(x, y)
    bullet.pd()
    bullet.circle(2)

def key_left():
    global userx
    pass
    userx += -10
    print(userx)

def key_right():
    global userx
    pass
    userx += 10
    print(userx)

def key_space():
    pass # your code here
    global x
    global y
    global bullets
    x = userx
    while y <= 300:
        time.sleep(0.5)
        y += 4
    else: y = 0
    bullets += (x,y)

def physics():
    global bullets
    global enemies
    pass

def ai():
    global enemies
    global gameover
    pass

def reset():
    global enemies
    global bullets
    global userx
    global gameover
    pass

def main():
    turtle.tracer(0,0)
    turtle.hideturtle()
    turtle.onkey(key_left, "Left")
    turtle.onkey(key_right, "Right")
    turtle.onkey(key_space, "space")
    turtle.listen()
    reset()
    while not gameover:
        turtle.clear()
        physics()
        ai()
        frame()
        turtle.update()
        time.sleep(0.05)

main()
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not crashing because of that `pass` ?

Comment: We can't help you with just this snippet of code, we're going to need more context. Also, don't use `time.sleep`, but use the default tkinter display loop (like [`after`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.after-method)).

Comment: @F.Leone, it's not the pass I got rid of it just now to check and the problem persists

Comment: There is no draw command inside the while - it will sleep 1 second and increase y until it reaches 301 or more.  SInce when can you combine a `else:` with `while` - I have never seen that before.... Is there some kind of async draw using y running beside that? wow: [else on while](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3295938/else-clause-on-python-while-statement) - learned smth.

Comment: `the program crashes` - that's not very descriptive, can you explain that better?

Comment: @Coal_ i updated the question to add the entire code as it is written thus far

Comment: use [ontimer()](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/turtle.html#turtle.ontimer) to execute function in intervals - and you will no need `sleep` (ontimer use time in milliseconds 0.5s = 500ms)

Comment: @wwii when I run the game and hit space bar to trigger the bullet function, a single bullet will appear stationary above the ship and then the launcher will freeze and remain frozen until i restart the program

Comment: turtle (similar to GUI frameworks) runs mainloop (event loop) which gets events from system, sends event to object, redraws items, etc. If you run long-running function (ie. you use `sleep` or `while` loop) then it doesn't returns to mainloop and mainloop can't get events, updates items, etc., and it looks like it freezes

Comment: @furas where would i use the ontimer function? i'm trying not to call any turtle functions outisde of the frame() function (if possible) and the bullets themselves are not actually turtles.

Comment: inside `key_space` you could  use ie. ontimer(500, move_bullet) to run new function `move_bullet`) and `turtle/mainloop` will run it every 500ms but it will not block mainloop - and you don't need `while` inside.

Comment: I see you have `while not gameover:` so you will no need `ontimer()` - `while not gameover:` can execute function which will move bullets in evry loop.

Answer (score 1):

I would:

```
def key_space():
    # simply spawn a new bullet and put it into your bullets list 

def advance_bullet(): # call this after paintnig all bullets in frame 
    # iterate over all bullets inside bullets, advance the Y position by 3

def frame(): 
    # add code to paint all bullets inside bullets - and call advance_bullets()
```

In the code that checks for collision with enemies:

```
# remove a bullet from bullets when its outside your screen (or passed all enemies max y coord) - no need to track that bullet anymore
```

if you ned to advance the bullets slower then your main loops intervall, make a "framespassed" counter and see if `framespassed % something == 0` and only then advance your bullets.

**Adapted to what you already have**

You need to change these parts:

```
def frame():
    global bullets
    pass
    ship = turtle.Turtle()
    ship.pu()
    ship.ht()
    ship.setpos(userx, -300)
    ship.pd()
    ship.circle(5)

    # debugging all bullets: 
    # print(bullets) # remove this

    for idx in range(0,len(bullets)): # paint ALL bullets in the bullets list
        bulletTurtle = turtle.Turtle()
        b = bullets[idx] # current bullet we are painting
        bulletTurtle.pu()
        bulletTurtle.ht()
        bulletTurtle.setpos(b[0], b[1])
        bulletTurtle.pd()
        bulletTurtle.circle(2)
        b[1] += 13 # quick and dirty approach, move bulltet after painting
                   # to save another complete bullets-foreach-loop 

    # quick n dirty bullet removal for out of screen bullets
    # normally I would do this probably in your "check if enemy hit" 
    # method as you are going over bullets there as well and can remove
    # them as soon as they passed all enemies 
    bullets = [x for x in bullets if x[1] < 500] 


def key_space():
    global x
    global y
    global bullets
    bullets.append([userx,-300]) # start a new bullet at current player position
```

Edit:

You might want to take a look at turtle.shape, turtle.size and turtle.stamp - by using a "circle" shape and a size that fits, you might be able to "stamp" this shape down. Advantage: you can simply delete the stamped shape - by its integer-id. I haven*t worked with turtle ever - consider yourself if that would be a way to easily redraw your players position and/or bullets

Answer (score 1):

It is not ideal but it starts working.

In `key_space` you only add new bullet to list.
In `while not gameover` you run function which will move all bullets.
In `frame` you draw all bullets.

```
import turtle
import time

userx = 0

x = 0
y = -300

enemies = [(300,50, "left"), (400,50, "left"), (350, -50, "right")]

bullets = []

gameover = False

def frame():
    pass
    ship = turtle.Turtle()
    ship.pu()
    ship.ht()
    ship.setpos(userx, -300)
    ship.pd()
    ship.circle(5)

    # redraw bullets
    for x, y in bullets:
        bullet = turtle.Turtle()
        bullet.pu()
        bullet.ht()
        bullet.setpos(x, y)
        bullet.pd()
        bullet.circle(2)

def key_left():
    global userx
    pass
    userx += -10
    print(userx)

def key_right():
    global userx
    pass
    userx += 10
    print(userx)

def key_space():
    pass # your code here
    global x
    global y
    global bullets
    x = userx

    # add bullet to list
    bullets.append([x, -300])

def move_bullets():
    global bullets

    live_bullets = []

    # move every bullet and check if should still live
    for x, y in bullets:
        y += 4

        # keep only some bullets and other forget (kill/remove)
        if y <= 300:
            live_bullets.append([x, y])

    bullets = live_bullets

def physics():
    global bullets
    global enemies
    pass

def ai():
    global enemies
    global gameover
    pass

def reset():
    global enemies
    global bullets
    global userx
    global gameover
    pass

def main():
    turtle.tracer(0,0)
    turtle.hideturtle()
    turtle.onkey(key_left, "Left")
    turtle.onkey(key_right, "Right")
    turtle.onkey(key_space, "space")
    turtle.listen()
    reset()
    while not gameover:
        turtle.clear()
        physics()
        ai()
        move_bullets() # <--  move bullets (or maybe before physics)
        frame()
        turtle.update()
        time.sleep(0.05)

main()
```