# A way to input a multiple word string to search multiple matching dictionary keys?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there a way to input a multiple word string to search multiple matching dictionary keys? - Thank you.

```
def concept(word):
# use this to list python file titles and links to open them in a new tab
files    = {1:"http://file_title0001.py",
            2:"file_title0002.txt",
            3:"file_title0003.txt",
            4:"file_title0004.txt",
            5:"file_title0005.txt",
            6:"file_title0006.txt",
            7:"file_title0007.txt",    
            8:"file_title0008.txt",
            9:"file_title0009.txt"}
# change keys to searchable simple keyword phrases. 
concepts = {'GAMES':[1,2,4,3,3],
            'BLACKJACK':[5,3,5,3,5],
            'MACHINE':[4,9,9,9,4],
            'DATABASE':[5,3,3,3,5],
            'LEARNING':[4,9,4,9,4]}
if word.upper() not in concepts:
    print("Nothing Found in Database")
    return
for pattern in concepts[word.upper()]:
    print(files[pattern])

while True:
    concept(input("Enter Concept Idea: "))
    print("\n")
```

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3295938/else-clause-on-python-while-statement).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
def print_big(word):
    # use this to list python file titles and links to open them in a new tab
    files = {1:"http://file_title0001.py",
            2:"file_title0002.txt",
            3:"file_title0003.txt",
            4:"file_title0004.txt",
            5:"file_title0005.txt",
            6:"file_title0006.txt",
            7:"file_title0007.txt",    
            8:"file_title0008.txt",
            9:"file_title0009.txt"}
    # change keys to searchable simple keyword phrases. 
    concepts = {'GAMES':[1,2,4,3,3],
                'BLACKJACK':[5,3,5,3,5],
                'MACHINE':[4,9,9,9,4],
                'DATABASE':[5,3,3,3,5],
                'LEARNING':[4,9,4,9,4]}
    if word.upper() not in concepts:
        print("Nothing Found in Database")
        return
    for pattern in concepts[word.upper()]:
        print(files[pattern])

print_big(input("Enter Concept Idea: "))
```

Comment: @Aneikei No problem! Please mark this answer as a solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `try/except` clause to cover the case in which the key is not present (`KeyError`):

```
try:
    for pattern in concepts[word.upper()]:
        print(files[pattern])
except KeyError as err:
    print("Nothing Found in Database for '{}'".format(err))
```