# "IndexError: string index out of range"

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to write a simple program that tells you how many digits of e (from mathematics) are equal to your approximation...it works if there are one or more digits incorrect, but if not this pops up:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "&^%%@%#", line 5, in <module>
    while e[c] == ue[c]:
IndexError: string index out of range
```

I have tried if statements, more while statements and more functions, but it won't work. Here's the code:

```
e = str(2.7182818284590452353602874713526624977572470936999595)
ue = str(input("Copy in your version of e and this will check it ! "))

c = 0
while e[c] == ue[c]:
    if c < len(ue):
        c = c + 1
else:
    break

print(c - 1)
```

If I input `2.79` it shows up with 3.
Though if I input, say `2.718` and all digits are correct it says this:

```
IndexError: string index out of range (Coming from line 5)
```

(Also this is my first time on Stack Overflow; so cut me some slack.)

Comment: explain what are you trying to do here

Comment: Your indentation of the `else` line is incorrect. It should be aligned with `if`. Currently it is a [`while..else`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3295938/else-clause-on-python-while-statement) block.

Comment: Note how you're checking `len(ue)` *after* doing `ue[c]` If `c` is out of bounds, it will cause an error there. You need to do the check before trying to index.

Comment: Selcuk so true, thanks!

Comment: Ok, to clarify I'm writing a program that sees how many digits are correct in your e (may be found in another program) compared to the actual e (found elsewhere).

Comment: Problem is this program only works when a digit is INCORRECT like: 2.711

Comment: If it's like 2.718 (*all digits are CORRECT*) it crashes, so I want to make it NOT crash and just give me c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that your variables `e` and `ue` doens't have the same length.

**When you are converting float into string you are losing precision.**

```
e = str(2.7182818284590452353602874713526624977572470936999595)
ue = input("Copy in your version of e and this will check it ! ")

print (e) # 2.718281828459045
print (ue) # 2.7182818284590452353602874713526624977572470936999595
```

Define a string  with `double` or `single` quotes:

```
e = '2.7182818284590452353602874713526624977572470936999595'
ue = input("Copy in your version of e and this will check it ! ")

c = 0
while e[c] == ue[c]:
    if c < len(ue)-1:
        c = c + 1
    else:
        break
print(c - 1)
```

output:

```
Copy in your version of e and this will check it ! 2.7182818284590452353602874713526624977572470936999595
52
```