# Why is my simple else statement not working correctly in my while loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, while-loop

I'm a noob and probably dumb, but help is appreciated greatly. I want to know why the code finishes when it executes the "else" statement, I want it to continue the "while" loop.

```
import random
happy == "no"
while happy == "no":
    stat = random.randint(1,50)
    print (stat)
    happy = input("Are you happy with this?" )
    if happy == "yes":
        print("Okay moving on. ")
        break
else:
    print("Please enter a valid answer. ")
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `else` should be at the same indent level of `if`, and you're trying to make a comparison (`==`) in the second line instead of defining the variable `happy` to be `no` (with `=`). This is the fixed code, which I could verify works for me in Python 3.7.4:

```py
import random
happy = "no"
while happy == "no":
    stat = random.randint(1,50)
    print (stat)
    happy = input("Are you happy with this?" )
    if happy == "yes":
        print("Okay moving on. ")
        break
    else:
        print("Please enter a valid answer. ")
```

The `else` clause in `while` is for [a specific purpose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3295938/else-clause-on-python-while-statement) - somewhat counterintuitive even for non-beginner Python developers (let alone newcomers). You stumbled upon this construct "by accident", that's why your code didn't throw a `SyntaxError` and may have mislead you during debugging.

Comment: Hi, sorry I formatted the code in my question wrong!! In my actual code the indentation is correct (the same as you posted) but the code still terminates after executing the "else" statement rather than re-rolling the "stat".

Comment: The "else" statement is also triggered when the user enters "no" as an answer, even though it is a valid answer. I don't know why this is

Comment: Worked correctly for me here with Python 3.7.4. I did have to change the second line to `happy = "yes"` (removing one `=`). But it threw an error before that, so this is unlikely to be it.

Comment: Argh, just cant understand why it terminates!

Comment: There’s a number of moving gears involved - Python version, operating system, IDE, etc. There’s also problems with the copy-and-paste: the indent came wrong at first and it's weird that the code ran at all with `==` in the second line. I would triple-check that you’re copy-pasting the code you’re actually running and also add as many information as you can to the question. Record your screen if you must. With what I’m seeing in the question, there’s not much I (or anyone) can do to help diagnose your issue.

Comment: My friend fixed the code by changing my While Loop. He changed "while happy == "no" to "while True". And he explained that the reason it didn't work before was because the "else" statement was still changing the "happy" variable, because I asked the user to input a string for it in the previous "if" statement. Thanks for all help.

Comment: That would work as well, but I still have no idea why the code I posted works for me and not for you 

Answer (score 1):

The answer is because your indentation. [Indentation is very important in Python](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/indentation.html).

What you want to do is move the `else` statement to the same indentation level of `if`, so that way the logic says:

`Check if this condition is true, otherwise (else), do this`

A simple indent should fix your problem.

```
import random
happy = "no"
while happy == "no":
    stat = random.randint(1,50)
    print (stat)
    happy = input("Are you happy with this?" )
    if happy == "yes":
        print("Okay moving on. ")
        break
    else:
        print("Please enter a valid answer. ")
```

Comment: Hi, sorry I formatted the code in my question wrong!! In my actual code the indentation is correct (the same as you posted) but the code still terminates after executing the "else" statement rather than re-rolling the "stat".

Comment: The "else" statement is also triggered when the user enters "no" as an answer, even though it is a valid answer. I don't know why this is

Answer (score 0):

My friend fixed the code by changing my While Loop. He changed "while happy == "no" to "while True". And he explained that the reason it didn't work before was because the "else" statement was still changing the "happy" variable, because I asked the user to input a string for it in the previous "if" statement.