# How can I break the while loop on Python?

Tags: python

I'm starting with Python.
I can't make this `else` condition work. The while loop doesn't break.

**Code :**

```
list = []
uniques = []
start = False

while start:
    new_item = input('Add item: ')
    list.append(new_item)
    if new_item.lower == 'start':
        start = True
else:
    for number in list:
        if number not in uniques:
            uniques.append(number)
uniques.sort()
print(uniques)
```

Comment: You should be able to add a `break` on the line after `start = False`

Comment: your  `else:`  needs to be indented properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can't make this else condition work.

Your indentation is wrong. That's the reason your code is not working for the else condition. Your code should be as follows -

```
list = []
uniques = []
start = True                          # In your question you have mentioned it as False here. 
                                      # It should be True for your loop to start.

while start:
    new_item = input('Add item: ')
    list.append(new_item)
    if new_item.lower() == 'start':   # You probably meant .lower() here and not .lower
        start = False
    else:                             # Properly indented this else statement
        for number in list:
            if number not in uniques:
                uniques.append(number)
uniques.sort()
print(uniques)
```

Also, if you are wondering why python didn't give error even though `else:` was after `while :`, you can refer - [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9979970/why-does-python-use-else-after-for-and-while-loops) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3295938/else-clause-on-python-while-statement) .

Answer (score 0):

By typing "break".
For example:

```
while(True):
    if(condition):
        break
# This code is reachable
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing new_item.lower to new_item.lower() should fix your issue.

- new_item is of type str, new_item.lower() runs the lower() method on that string object and returns the result.

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your indentation here as @Abhishek mentioned. But the reason why your while loop is not breaking is because of the line of code where you do

```
if new_item.lower == 'start':
```

@Abhishek has also pointed this out in his code sample but I will elaborate a little more
, Here new_item.lower is a function object but you are not running that function. To actually run the function you have to use

```
if new_item.lower() == 'start:
```

this converts the `new_item` string into all lower case as you are trying to do here. Just `new_item.lower` is just a pointer to the function. If you actually print out `new_item.lower` you can see that it shows something like `<built-in method lower of str object at 0x7f5144522cb0>` which is telling you that it is a function at the said memory location. So in your line you are comparing whether a function is equal to the string `'start'` where what you actually want to do is to see whether the result of the function acting on new_line is equal to the string `'start'`.