# My while loop keeps repeating even when its suppose to reach the limit

Tags: python

I'm new to python, and for some reason my while loop in def hint system still repeats when it reaches the limit. Here's the code to my "guessing game."

```
print ("guessing game 1 - 10\n\n")
import random
number = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

random.shuffle (number)
result = (number [0] )
secret_number = (result)
guess_count = 0
guess_limit = 3

def hint_system ():
    hint_count = 0
    hint_limit = 1
    while hint_count < hint_limit:
        hint_request = input('Would you like to use your hint?, Yes or no?: ')  
        hint_count += 1
        if guess > secret_number:
            print("lower")
        elif guess < secret_number:
            print ("higher")
            break
        else:
            print ("Hint not used") 
    else:
        print("\n\n")
        print("Hint used up")
        
while guess_count < guess_limit:
    guess = int(input( "Guess: "))
    guess_count += 1
    hint_system ( )
    if guess == secret_number:
        print("congrats you win!")
        break
    else:
        print("You failed!")
        print("correct answer: "+ str(secret_number))
```

The result is

guessing game 1 - 10

Guess: 2
Would you like to use your hint?, Yes or no?: yes

higher

Guess: 2
Would you like to use your hint?, Yes or no?:

Comment: Indentation is significant in python so please format your code.   Import should be first thing in your file.  hint_request is not used so why ask?

Comment: You ask if they want to use a hint, but then assume they said yes. But when you call `hint_system` again, the hint count (a local variable) is reset to 0.

Comment: It's a really good idea to keep variables close to where they are used.

Comment: A suggestion: what happens if the user says they don't want to use a hint? `hint_request` is assigned, but never used anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `break`, the `else` clause after the `while` doesn't get executed.

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3295938/else-clause-on-python-while-statement) for more.

Answer (score 0):

You keep resetting the hint function so the hint count keeps going to 0, so it will continue indefinitely.

It is best to keep the hint count variable as a variable in the function:

```
def func(hint_count):
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The logic of the game didn't make much sense to me so I reworked it as follows.  It generates a secret, and you get 3 guesses.  If the guess is wrong then you are asked if you want a hint:

```
import random
import sys


def hint_system(secret):
    if guess > secret:
        print("lower")
    elif guess < secret:
        print("higher")


guess_range = (1, 10)
guess_attempts = 3
print(f"guessing game {guess_range[0]} to {guess_range[1]}\n")

secret = random.randint(guess_range[0], guess_range[1])
for attempt in range(guess_attempts):
    guess = int(input("Guess: "))
    if guess == secret:
        print("congrats you win!")
        sys.exit()
    else:
        print("Sorry. This is not correct.")
        if input('Would you like to use your hint (yes/no)? ') != 'no':
            hint_system(secret)

print(f"You failed! The correct answer was {secret}")
```

and here is an example session:

```
guessing game 1 to 10

Guess: 5
Sorry. This is not correct.
Would you like to use your hint (yes/no)? yes
higher
Guess: 8
Sorry. This is not correct.
Would you like to use your hint (yes/no)? no
Guess: 9
Sorry. This is not correct.
Would you like to use your hint (yes/no)? yes
lower
You failed! The correct answer was 6
```