# clause in python meaning

Tags: python, python-3.x, terminology, clause

I was reading the python documentation and noticed the word `clause` being used in parts of sentences like: `the try clause (the statement(s) between the try and except keywords) is executed`, or `Loop statements may have an else clause`. What does `clause` mean?

Comment: It's in your quote *the statement(s) between the try and except keywords*

Comment: @Guy what would it mean for `loop statements to have an else clause` (my second example)? don't else statements come by them self, just the word `else`?

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3295938/else-clause-on-python-while-statement. And `else` will never be stand alone, it will come after a loop or, more commonly, `if`/ `elif`.

Comment: so clause can basically be somewhere, for example: `if something:`, something being the clause. While clause can also be something after that if statement like say a print() if that if statement turns out to be true, correct?

Comment: No, `something` will be the condition. The clause will be everything inside the `if` block, i.e. from the next line until the code after the `if` is ended (marked by an indentation to the left).

Comment: would code inside a function `def myFunction():` be considered clause?

Answer (score 0):

Clause, or more precisely a definite clause grammar, is a part of the the grammar used to define a programming language.  Here is how it's defined for compound statements:

> A compound statement consists of one or more ‘clauses.’ A clause consists of a header and a ‘suite.’ The clause headers of a particular compound statement are all at the same indentation level. Each clause header begins with a uniquely identifying keyword and ends with a colon. A suite is a group of statements controlled by a clause. A suite can be one or more semicolon-separated simple statements on the same line as the header, following the header’s colon, or it can be one or more indented statements on subsequent lines. [compound statements](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html)

> compound_stmt ::=  ...
> | while_stmt
> ...\

> while_stmt ::=  "while" assignment_expression ":" suite
> ...\

So the `while_stmt` or the equivalent right side `"while" assignment_expression ":" suite` is an example of a clause.

Comment: Isnt that what `syntax` is, basically the rules AKA grammar for the programming language?

Comment: Clause would be a part of the grammar or syntax.

Comment: that could mean a couple of things, can your narrow down on what you mean?