# `goto` in Python

Tags: python, compilation, bytecode, goto

I must use `goto` in Python. I found [entrians `goto`](http://entrian.com/goto/) but my Python implementation (CPython 2.7.1 on Mac) does not have this module, so it doesn't seem to be portable. It should at least work in all Python implementations which support CPython bytecode (esp. I care about CPython and PyPy). Then there is [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/438844/is-there-a-label-goto-in-python), and [cdjc's `goto`](https://github.com/cdjc/goto). And the ones given by answers below.

I could go and build up the bytecode manually (i.e. write my own Python compiler) because there is such an instruction (`JUMP_ABSOLUTE` and friends). But I wonder if there is an easier way. Is it possible via `inspect` or so to call a single bytecode instruction? I also thought about compiling via Python and then automatically patching the generated Python bytecode.

---

Of course, people will ask why and will not give me any helpful answer if I don't explain why I really really need this. So in short my use case: I am translating a C AST to Python AST and compiling this. I can map every logical flow (all the loops and other stuff) in some way to equivalent Python code. Everything except `goto`. Related projects: [PyCParser](https://github.com/albertz/PyCParser) (see [`interpreter.py`](https://github.com/albertz/PyCParser/blob/master/interpreter.py)), [PyCPython](https://github.com/albertz/PyCPython), [PyLua](https://github.com/albertz/PyLua).

Comment: Translating C to Python? WTF. Just... why the heck would one need this and how could it ever be practical? (It sounds like a very fun challenge, admittedly.) Also, are you aware that that module is an april's fools joke and only works by inspecting the source code and doing hackery which I wouldn't assume to be the slightest bit portable?

Comment: +1 for actually explaining why you think you need `goto`.

Comment: @delnan: Well, the fun factor is indeed one of the main reasons. :) Otherwise, I think it might be useful in some cases to have something like Python or Lua embedded. And for debugging of C code in general. Via PyPy JIT compiling, it even might not be that slow.

Comment: I don't think that what you are trying to achieve will not break one way or another the python objects' reference count.

Comment: [The goto decorator (Python recipe)](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576944-the-goto-decorator/)

Comment: @Paolo: Yea, looks exactly what I was searching for (what I meant by patching the bytecode)! Just put that into an answer. :) Works with both CPython and PyPy.

Comment: See also: http://entrian.com/goto/download.html

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I know what everybody is thinking:

[image: xkcd GOTO]

However, there might be some didactic cases where you actually need a `goto`.

This python recipe provides the `goto` command as a function decorator.

[**The goto decorator**](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576944-the-goto-decorator/) (*Python recipe by Carl Cerecke*)

> This is the recipe for you if you are sick of the slow speed of the
>   existing `goto` module http://entrian.com/goto/. The `goto` in this
>   recipe is about 60x faster and is also cleaner (abusing `sys.settrace`
>   seems hardly pythonic). Because this is a decorator, it alerts the
>   reader which functions use `goto`.  It does not implement the comefrom
>   command, although it is not difficult to extend it to do so (exercise
>   for the reader).  Also, computed gotos aren't supported; they're not
>   pythonic.
>
> - Use `dis.dis(fn)` to show the bytecode disassembly of a function.
> - The bytecodes of a function are accessed by `fn.func_code.co_code`.
>     This is readonly so:
> - The decorated function is created exactly the same as the old one,
>     but with the bytecode updated to obey the `goto` commands.
> - This is 2.x only; the new module is not in python 3.x (another
>     exercise for the reader!)

**Usage**

```
@goto
def test1(n):
    s = 0

    label .myLoop

    if n <= 0:
        return s
    s += n
    n -= 1

    goto .myLoop

>>> test1(10)
55
```

---

**Update**

Here're two additional implementations compatible with Python 3:

- https://github.com/cdjc/goto
- https://github.com/snoack/python-goto

Comment: It is funny that the recipe author is considering "pythonicity" ("abusing sys.settrace seems hardly pythonic") when implementing a goto :) Anyway, great answer!

Answer (score 9):

You may have the only valid use case I have ever seen for needing `goto` in Python. :-)

The most straightforward way to emulate forward `goto` in Python is using exceptions, as these can jump out of any depth of nested control structures.

```
class Goto(Exception):
    pass

try:
    if foo = "bar":
        raise Goto
    print "foo is not bar"
except Goto:
    print "foo is bar"
```

This gets hairy if you need to support more than one destination, but I think it could be done using nested `try/except` structures and multiple classes of exception, one for each destination. Since C limits `goto` to the scope of a single function, at least you won't have to worry about how to make this work *across* functions.  :-)  Of course, it doesn't work for reverse `goto`s.

Another thing to note is that exceptions in Python, while fast compared to some languages, are still slower than normal flow control structures such as `while` and `for`.

This could be a lot of work (though perhaps not more than you're already in for), but if you could generate Python bytecode rather than Python source, you would have no problem implementing `goto`, because Python bytecode (like most psuedo-machine-languages) has a perfectly cromulent `JUMP_ABSOLUTE` opcode.

Comment: Unfortunately, in some cases where I see `goto` in C, those are reverse ones. And I need a solution which just works always (otherwise it is not worth to implement it, esp. if it is such complicated).

Answer (score 5):

I've updated my python goto decorator for Python 3. You can get it at https://github.com/cdjc/goto. Using goto instead of functions can make a state machine about 5 times faster.

The version for python 2 is still available at http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576944-the-goto-decorator/ but it has a number of bugs that are fixed in the python 3 version.

Comment: "Using goto instead of functions can make a state machine about 5 times faster."-- Having originally learned to program in a now-archaic dialect of BASIC (where GOTO and GOSUB were the *only* flow control) I often find myself explaining to young programmers who have been taught that "goto is inherently evil" that goto is actually more like dynamite. In the hands of an expert it can remove major obstacles from your codepath in a clear, concise, rapidly-executable manner. In the hands of an idiot it results in sticky gobbets of your code being splattered all over the landscape...

Answer (score 1):

There are going to be some common patterns that code using `goto` is likely to follow.

In most cases, I suspect that all goto statements will jump to a location that's both later, and in a more enclosing block;  If a function body follows this pattern perfectly, transform the goto's into exceptions, with the labels as the except blocks.

Other cases of goto jumping from the one place to another in the same block, as would be used in a state machine.  This can probably be translated into a dispatch loop; each region between a label and the next becomes a function; goto's are replaced by `next_state = 'labelname'; return`

The last case, which is neither of the above and possibly non-trivial, are when the jump is *into* a loop body.  I don't have an answer for that yet.

Comment: "The last case, which is neither of the above and possibly non-trivial, are when the jump is into a loop body." I think you could work out something using generators for that.

Comment: I actually hope I can avoid implementing several independent solutions for several cases. The most general case is actual the state machine which always works (if I also translate all the other loops this way) but I'm afraid that by using `next_state = 'label'` etc., the PyPy JIT cannot really optimize it that well anymore and I don't want to loose that.

Answer (score 1):

This is not exactly what you're looking for but hear me out.

Many years ago, my son and I wrote an "Adventure" game in BASIC. Each location in the underground game was a line number. When you left one location through the tunnel going north, for instance, you arrived at another location.

The coding was something like `if response == 'N' GOTO 2400`. So players ended up going all over the place using GOTOs.

I wondered how this might be done in Python and came up with this.

Maybe such a technique could be used for other applications where something like a GOTO is needed. If you split up your program into chunks which are functions, the following "a bit silly" coding would do the trick.

```
""" Simple, short and unfinished 'Adventure' game to show how a program such
as this with 'locations' (where each location is handled by a function) can
simulate 'GOTO's through use of the eval() function. Each time the player
chooses an exit from his current location, where he goes to will depend on the
exit chosen and achieved using eval() on the last line.

This saves having to code a series of 'if's at each location which call the
correct function the player goes to. Also, because the code always comes back
to the eval line at the botton each time, one location's function doesn't call
the next location's function, with possible risk of stack overflow if the
program is radically extended.

The program uses randint() to determine if characters are there and what they
are doing. This is just a taster. Dramatic improvements could be made if the
player could collect and use artefacts found during his travels. For instance
if there was a key somewhere and it was collected, it could be used to unlock
the door, but the key can't be picked up unless the troll isn't there etc.
The program needs to be able to parse (understand) simple natural language
(English) commands such as 'take key' or 'unlock door' or 'give food to troll'
There will also need to be some global variables so each function can behave
and do stuff dependent on these variables.

The program needs to be able to respond to players' commands, such as after a
player has indicated which direction he wants to go, the program responds,
'You can't go that way. the Ork is blocking your path'. You get the picture.

The program also needs to be able to save variables in a dictionary (which is
then pickled into a file) so players can close the game and save it and pick up
where they left off next time.

People new to this sort of game should realise by the way, that just because
a tunnel (or other route) leaves one location northwards, that doesn't mean
that it arrives at the next location from the south. The tunnels twist and
turn all over the place."""


def l0():
    #print('L0')
    print("You're south of a forbidding-looking cave")
    go = input('n or q > ')
    if go == 'n': return('1')
    if go == 'q': return('q')
    else: return 'q'

def l1():
    #print('L1')
    print("You're in a large, dark cave. Bats are hanging from the ceiling.")
    print("Tunnels lead north, east and west. The entrance is south of you.")
    go = input('n s e w > ')
    if go == 'n': return('3') # Leaving L1 northwards takes you to L3
    if go == 's': return('0') # Leaving L1 southwards takes you to L0
    if go == 'e': return('3') # Leaving L1 eastwards also takes you to L3
    if go == 'w': return('2') # Leaving L1 westwards takes you to L2
    else: return 'q'

def l2():
    #print('L2')
    print("You've come to a bridge running east across a chasm")
    print("On the other side the only way to go is through a tunnel")
    print("This side of the chasm, a tunnel leads north and a path leads south")
    go = input('n e s > ')
    if go == 'n': return('1') # As per L! but applicable to L2 etc.
    if go == 'e': return('4')
    if go == 's': return('3')
    else: return 'q'

def l3():
    #print('L3')
    print("You've come to a hot and humid cavern")
    print("Tunnels run north, east and west. A path leads south.")
    print("There's a dragon here.")
    dstate = randint(1,5)
    if dstate == 1: print("The dragon seems to be asleep")
    if dstate == 2: print("The dragon looks sleepy")
    if dstate == 3: print("The dragon is awake")
    if dstate == 4: print("The dragon looks angry")
    if dstate == 5: print("The dragon is breathing fire and very angry!")
    go = input('n s e w > ')
    if go == 'n': return('1')
    if go == 's': return('2')
    if go == 'e': return('4')
    if go == 'w': return('1')
    else: return 'q'

def l4():
    #print('L4')
    print("You've arrived at a grotto. There are jewels here!")
    tstate = randint(1,4)
    if tstate > 1: print("There's a troll here wielding a cudgel")
    print("Tunnels lead east, west and south from here")
    go = input('s e w > ')
    if go == 's': return('5')
    if go == 'e': return('2')
    if go == 'w': return('3')
    else: return 'q'

def l5():
    #print('L5')
    print("The tunnel ends at a door leading to a small room")
    print("Through a grille in the door, you can see there is no way out")
    print("The only way is back, south along the tunnel")
    print("But there's gold in the room!")
    print("The door is locked.")
    go = input('s > ')
    if go == 's': return('4')
    else: return 'q'

### ********************* Main Program Start ***************************

import random
from random import randint

go = l0()   # That's call L zero (location zero), not ten!

while go != 'q':
    print()
    go = eval("l"+go+"()")  # Program always returns here to sort out where to
                            # go next. Player doesn't of course!
```

Comment: Instead of `return('4')` why not just return the function itself: `return l4`. Main loop then becomes `while go: go = go()`

Answer (score 0):

A working version has been made: http://entrian.com/goto/.

Note: It was offered as an April Fool's joke. (working though)

```
# Example 1: Breaking out from a deeply nested loop:
from goto import goto, label

for i in range(1, 10):
    for j in range(1, 20):
        for k in range(1, 30):
            print i, j, k
            if k == 3:
                goto .end
label .end
print "Finished\n"
```

Needless to say. Yes its funny, but DONT use it.