# How do I loop back to a part of my program in python?

Tags: python, loops

So I've been trying to make a python program for a cypher my firend and I did (joined 2 different cyphers) and I've been stuck trying to make it easy to encrypt different string without opening and closing the program every time. I'm using python 3.2 on a 64-bit windows 7 computer.

Here is my code (please also give me tips to polish it a bit):

```
#!/usr/bin/python

#from string import maketrans   # Required to call maketrans function.

print ("Welcome to the Rotten Bat encription program. Coded in python by Diego Granada")
answer = input("Please enter the password: ")
if answer == 'raindrops':
    print("Password accepted")
else:
    print ("Incorrect password. Quiting")
    from time import sleep
    sleep(3)
    exit()
intab = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
outtab = "N9Q2T1VWXYZ7B3D5F8H4JK60n9pq2st1vwxyz7b3d5f8h4jk60"

message = input("Put your message here: ")

print(message.translate(dict((ord(x), y) for (x, y) in zip(intab, outtab))))

print ("Thank you for using this program")

input()
```

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/438844/is-there-a-label-in-python

Comment: functions, man, functions.

Comment: Python is a highly structured language, so take advantage of that.

Comment: The simplest thing would be to put a while loop around the whole program.

Comment: Or just a while True loop right after the password check so it keeps doing the input and translation

Comment: Why is your `outtab` 2 characters shorter than your `intap`?

Comment: Use [`getpass`](http://docs.python.org/library/getpass.html#getpass.getpass) when asking for a password.

Comment: The given answer belows shows you.

Answer (score 6):

Good programming practice is to break your code into modular units of functionality - for instance, one function that actually *does* the cipher, one function that gathers user input, etc. The more advanced and more modular version of this idea is Object-Oriented Programming - used in most large projects and programming languages today. (If you're interested, there are many great resources to learn OOP, like [this tutorial](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/articles/OOP.shtml).)

Most simply, you could put your cipher itself into its own function, then call it every time the user inputs a message. This would do the trick:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

print ("Welcome to the Rotten Bat encription program. Coded in python by Diego Granada")
answer = input("Please enter the password: ")
if answer == 'raindrops':
    print("Password accepted")
else:
    print ("Incorrect password. Quiting")
    from time import sleep
    sleep(3)
    exit()

def cipher(message):
    intab = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    outtab = "N9Q2T1VWXYZ7B3D5F8H4JK60n9pq2st1vwxyz7b3d5f8h4jk60"
    return (message.translate(dict((ord(x), y) for (x, y) in zip(intab, outtab))))

while True:
    message = input("Put your message here: ")
    print cipher(message)
    print ("Thank you for using this program")
```

This program will now loop forever while asking the user for another message - use the key combination <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> to stop the program.

Comment: It's giving me a syntax error on line 20, highlighting cipher.

Comment: Be careful that you're not missing or adding any extra whitespace - Python uses it instead of braces and semicolons like other languages use. When I copy and paste the above sample into a file, it executes fine. Can you post the exact error?