# The equivalent of a GOTO in python

Tags: python, goto

I am self teaching myself python 2.7. I  have some experience in using BATCH, which has a GOTO statement.  How do I do that in python? For example, suppose I want to jump from line 5 to line 18.

I realize there have been previous questions regarding this topic, but I have not found them sufficiently informative or, are too high level in python for my current understanding.

Comment: @kojiro Please read the whole topic.

Comment: "One of thme mentioned a function, but i don't see how they would work." Understand how functions work, then you will see that you don't need `goto`.

Comment: ok,  I'll go do that Akavall

Comment: Random: If you really do want to use a goto, somebody actually wrote [a working version](http://entrian.com/goto/) as part of an April Fool's joke in 2004. By no means do I recommend actually using it, but I thought I'd link it for amusement's sake.

Comment: I   think whatever is the case, You must handle it by using while loop.

Comment: in some cases exceptions can be used to implement goto-like behavior if id none of the other structural constructs can do what you want.

Comment: Answer available in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/438844/is-there-a-label-goto-in-python/49052717#49052717. A failure handling in a function can be handled well with only goto statement.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

`Goto`s are universally reviled in computer science and programming as they lead to very unstructured code.

Python (like almost every programming language today) supports [structured programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structured_programming) which controls flow using if/then/else, loop and subroutines.

The key to thinking in a structured way is to understand how and why you are branching on code.

For example, lets pretend Python had a `goto` and corresponding `label` statement *shudder*. Look at the following code. In it if a number is greater than or equal to 0 we print if it

```
number = input()
if number < 0: goto negative
if number % 2 == 0:
   print "even"
else:
   print "odd"
goto end
label: negative
print "negative"
label: end
print "all done"
```

If we want to know when a piece of code is executed, we need to carefully traceback in the program, and examine how a label was arrived at - which is something that can't really be done.

For example, we can rewrite the above as:

```
number = input()
goto check

label: negative
print "negative"
goto end

label: check
if number < 0: goto negative
if number % 2 == 0:
   print "even"
else:
   print "odd"
goto end

label: end
print "all done"
```

Here, there are two possible ways to arrive at the "end", and we can't know which one was chosen. As programs get large this kind of problem gets worse and results in [spaghetti code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghetti_code)

In comparison, below is how you *would* write this program in Python:

```
number = input()
if number >= 0:
   if number % 2 == 0:
       print "even"
   else:
       print "odd"
else:
   print "negative"
print "all done"
```

I can look at a particular line of code, and know under what conditions it is met by tracing back the tree of `if/then/else` blocks it is in. For example, I know that the line `print "odd"` will be run when a `((number >= 0) == True) and ((number % 2 == 0) == False)`.

Comment: +1, Your explanation was great, and all of the code looks good, but as the scripts get bigger and bigger, you may not be able to deal with a negative in a single line. if/else begins piling up with indents off the screen. It may be better then if in this example you take the input, call `check()`, and in `check()`, call `negative()` if we've found the number to be negative. Furthermore, this would show how easy it is to take `label`s and go straight to functions (which our OP doesn't seem to entirely grasp)

Comment: @CalderHutchins On face value `goto`s seem harmless and straight forward enough to new programmers - "Goto this place and do stuff".  A lot of the time the reasons for why get lost in the mysts of time, but the rationales for structured programming still exist.

Comment: I'm only on my 3rd day learning python, give me a break ;)

Comment: @Josh If your code is indented off the screen thats indicative of the [arrow anti-pattern](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ArrowAntiPattern). Its not an argument against structured programming, just an argument against poorly thought out programs.

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr I understand, that's why I'm trying to tell you to teach the OP about using functions to avoid that now in a simple example like this before you send another one of *those* programmers out into the fray (as I said before, he doesn't seem to have very much of a grasp on functions)

Comment: @CalderHutchins Don't think my comment "On the face value..." was an insult or directed at you. More an explanation for others as to why new programmers ask about `goto`s. They do seem intuitive and in small programs are. The issues with `goto`s don't come up until thousands of lines in, a shortcut here, a shortcut there, and then an unmaintainable nightmare.

Comment: @ Lego Stormtroopr i was refering to josh xD.  I can understand why a goto might turn into a nightmare now.

Comment: More pythonic would be `if number % 2: print 'odd' else: print 'even'`

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Its would be, but I was writing it to be very explicit code.

Comment: “`goto`s are universally reviled in computer science and programming”—not quite. `goto` is perfect for error handling in C (eschewing RAII and exceptions), and for implementing structured programming constructs. Absolute statements are always—well, often—misguided.

Comment: @JonPurdy I originally had "considered universally reviled" which was a little less absolute. I didn't intent to argue the edit. You are right, they have their place as Tovalds and Knuth argued. However given the question, and the audience, I felt an absolute was ok.

Comment: I won't go against the universally accepted opinion that "goto is bad" (although I personally don't believe it), but I have to bring up a simple, also universal, fact:  All executable codes, from all languages, result to machine (assembly) code, which is actually *based* on jumps!  I am an assembly programmer and I never had a problem tracing back a jump and find the condition that had led to it, even if the *source* code wasn't mine.

Comment: So conditionally jumping to a particular part of the code isnt structured?  GOTO functions exist at the assembly level and have legitimate purpose.  There is no reason to remove functionality from a higher level language than what exists at the lower level.

Comment: an example of a bad program using goto does not answer the question

Comment: Try writing command parsers and methods that take config inputs that can lead to many different combination of possible code paths and you will realize why GOTO / JUMP  are the best fit for such situations.  GOTO allows you to write the cleanest code in such situations. Lets not be so dogmatic.

Comment: Like several other commenters, I disagree with the opinion that “`goto`s are universally reviled”. `goto`s are _dangerous_ because they _can_ lead to very unstructured code, and a beginner programmer would tend to use `goto` this bad way. *But* in _some_ situations `goto`s are really useful and actually lead to a _better_ code! So a more accurate answer would be: “Python does not allow for `goto`, to avoid beginner programmers to be tempted to misuse it”.

Comment: I'm working on a fortran to Python code conversion and that's pretty much I've implemented. Unstructured to Structured says it all!!

Comment: In a sense 'gotos' can be considered best practice: just write a statemachine, and convert your labels to states. So now no more gotos and if I remember correctly statemachines are considered good. (and the code even looks similiar)

Comment: Re: `goto` *universally reviled*—[GOTOphobia considered harmful (in C)](https://blog.joren.ga/gotophobia-harmful). That is about *C*, but Python is also largely procedural/imperative, and has the same basic facilities of control-flow.

Answer (score 77):

Forgive me - I couldn't resist ;-)

```
def goto(linenum):
    global line
    line = linenum

line = 1
while True:
    if line == 1:
        response = raw_input("yes or no? ")
        if response == "yes":
            goto(2)
        elif response == "no":
            goto(3)
        else:
            goto(100)
    elif line == 2:
        print "Thank you for the yes!"
        goto(20)
    elif line == 3:
        print "Thank you for the no!"
        goto(20)
    elif line == 20:
        break
    elif line == 100:
        print "You're annoying me - answer the question!"
        goto(1)
```

Comment: LOL!  Calder, it's a joke.  It's possible to write horrible code in **any** language ;-)

Comment: PLEASE DO IMPLEMENT [COME FROM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COME_FROM) NEXT?

Comment: lol tim i know it was a joke :p

Comment: It shows you have good programing aptitude :) insetting joke indeed

Comment: Wouldn't it be more pythonic to keep a dict of line numbers to functions? Like [this](http://pastebin.com/eqDksSnM) maybe. Or would it be better to make `end` raise something?

Comment: LOL - love the lambdas!  Of course the point was to make it as **un**-Pythonic as possible, and contorted lambdas sure help that along ;-)

Comment:  the most un-pythonic code I've ever seen, but at least you haven't used a switch statement 

Answer (score 47):

I entirely agree that `goto` is poor poor coding, but no one has actually answered the question. There **is** in fact a [goto module for Python](http://entrian.com/goto/) (though it was released as an April fool joke and is not recommended to be used, it *does* work).

Comment: as of Python 2.6.9 it does not work anymore...

Comment: Continuation passing style requires goto (in the guise of function calls).

Answer (score 9):

There's no `goto` instruction in the Python programming language. You'll have to write your code in a [structured](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structured_programming) way... But really, why do you want to use a `goto`? that's been [considered harmful](http://www.u.arizona.edu/~rubinson/copyright_violations/Go_To_Considered_Harmful.html) for decades, and any program you can think of can be written without using `goto`.

Of course, there are some [cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245742/examples-of-good-gotos-in-c-or-c) where an unconditional jump might be *useful*, but it's never *mandatory*, there will always exist a semantically equivalent, structured solution that doesn't need `goto`.

Comment: Thank-you, I wanted to use it to:  python askes the user a question and if the raw input is not yes or no it will ask another question about what the user meant.  Then it would go back to the line before the question was asked.

Comment: @CalderHutchins Can you explain what you mean by if it's not yes or not it asks another question?

Comment: @CalderHutchins:   That's trivial to do in a structured flow.  There's no need to create any jumps to arbitrary lines.

Comment: @CalderHutchins you don't need a `goto` for that, put the question inside a loop, if the answer is not valid then loop again until the input is right

Comment: I mean if you do not asnswer the question with yes or no, python will ask you if the answer you gave is similar to yes, or to no, basically i want it to learn by itself, of which i will have to find out how to make python edit it's own code, like BATCH can.

Comment: well *never need goto* and *there is always always structured equivalent* is true enough for python, but that's something you couldn't truly write when including assembly languages in the scope. Also python still has break and return which are gotos in disguise, and Exceptions are also arguably gotos in disguise.

Comment: @CalderHutchins You would be much better off using regex to check the input against a known list of possible variations which as others have suggested is easy to do with a simple while loop. If you want Python to write its own code, which it can, you may but it would have to write it to another file that's not in use and then run that file whichever way you choose.

Comment: it is a useful tool in certain circumstances, lets you do some tricks and you don't always want your code to be readable. Spaghetti coding in python could actually be really interesting

Answer (score 7):

*Disclaimer: I have been exposed to a significant amount of F77*

The modern equivalent of `goto` (arguable, only my opinion, etc) is explicit exception handling:

*Edited to highlight the code reuse better.*

Pretend pseudocode in a fake python-like language with `goto`:

```
def myfunc1(x)
    if x == 0:
        goto LABEL1
    return 1/x

def myfunc2(z)
    if z == 0:
        goto LABEL1
    return 1/z

myfunc1(0) 
myfunc2(0)

:LABEL1
print 'Cannot divide by zero'.
```

Compared to python:

```
def myfunc1(x):
    return 1/x

def myfunc2(y):
    return 1/y


try:
    myfunc1(0)
    myfunc2(0)
except ZeroDivisionError:
    print 'Cannot divide by zero'
```

Explicit named exceptions are a *significantly* better way to deal with non-linear conditional branching.

Comment: That's not a bad way of thinking about the *best possible* use of non-local gotos

Comment: Truth: >95% of GOTOs I have seen in the wild have been used for preemptive error handling.  The other 5% have been clever tricks that resulted in horrific bugs, and the code, as-is, couldn't even **be** translated to a different goto-less language without requiring changes to the algorithm.

Comment: @crjh: I'm very interested in seeing codes with `goto`s that cannot be directly translated to `goto`-less language. Can you give me example?

Comment: Think of multiple nested loops that `goto` between each other...a lot...

Comment: @justhalf I can't find the exact paper, but there is a proof that **all** programs that use `goto` can be rewritten to use while loops instead. Not cleanly mind you, but you can remove all `goto`s.

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr: you should be addressing that to cjrh, haha
But yeah, I guess the "not cleanly" part is what cjrh referred to as "requiring changes to the algorithm"

Comment: @Lego Stormtroopr: this is easy enough to prove. You can replace any goto using some memorized states. Usually even in difficult cases some booleans are enough, but you can look at the answer of Tim Peters as a proof that gotos are never necessary (because you can simulate them without having gotos).

Answer (score 4):

```
answer = None
while True:
    answer = raw_input("Do you like pie?")
    if answer in ("yes", "no"): break
    print "That is not a yes or a no"
```

Would give you what you want with no goto statement.

Comment: This is not a good idea. While it technically correct, it makes the logic very difficult to untangle.

Comment: It's better than goto.

Comment: I didn't even understand this.