# Goto statement in python - what other way is there?

Tags: python, goto

My program has the following scturcutre

1. program takes screenshot
   2, program looks for condition a. if condition a is not met, it need to go back to point 1
2. program looks for condition b. if condition b is not met, it need to go back to point 1
3. program looks for condition c. if condition c is not met, it need to go back to point 1
   ... etc

There are around 20 additional conditions and whenever one of them is not met, the program should return to the starting point. With a goto statement this could be easily solved. However, in Python this is not an option. Any suggestions are appreciated how this can be implemented elegantly.

Comment: Please show us the code you've written and we can let you know the most logical way.

Comment: There are situations when `goto` and labels are a good solution (or at least not worse than any other), using `goto` for loops is not one of them. You *do* know about the [`continue` statement](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops)?

Comment: use `while 1:` and `continue`.

Comment: You should really read the [official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial) (any tutorial for a modern programming language, really) if `goto` is still in your programming toolbox.

Comment: I would look into State Machine based solution, possibly.  Hard to tell wo more concrete code examples from your end.  Here's one so entry to get you started:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2101961/python-state-machine-design.

Comment: and re. goto being always useless, I beg to differ.  Maybe 5% of the time, I would like to have it available.  Things like *simple* error conditions and retries for example (not the OP's question however).  Try/except and loops do not always map directly to a plain English description of desired execution flow, sometimes a goto would have been better.  The point is moot in Python however, there is no goto.

Comment: It depends on how you define "useful." If you define it as "a feature that I might choose to use sometimes over more modern alternatives," then yes, `goto` is useful. If, however, you define it as "a feature that should have been included in the language because it is a good way to do some things and not an anti-pattern at all," then it's not useful. Python doesn't have moderately practical things like incrementors and TCO; I don't see why it would have something like `goto`.

Comment: while 1: and continue will do the trick I think and at the end break. thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The equivalent of a GOTO in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18863309/the-equivalent-of-a-goto-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should give us the code, or at least an example showing what the structure really is.

Maybe you could do so:

```
take screenshot
condition = (condition a) and (condition b) and ... and (condition z)

while (not condition):
    take screenshot
    condition = (condition a) and (condition b) and ... and (condition z)
```

Comment: This is close to what I would like to do, however if condition b is not met, I don't want to program to check for condition c. It should go back directly to do another screenshot and restart from the beginning with first checking condition a. then b and finally c only if both previous conditions were true.

Comment: As it is written, it will work as you want: boolean expressions with `and` are evaluated through short-circuit evaluation (also called lazy evaluation) in Python.
So if `condition b` is not met, Python evaluates the boolean expression `condition` to False without checking the value of `condition c` (if `condition b` is met, the program evaluates `condition c`, and so on...).