# GOTO in Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, goto, basic

I'm trying to rewrite an old basic program in Python but I have difficulties to manage the "goto" that do not exist in python
Is there a solution ?

Comment: Translate algorithms, not code.

Comment: I don't think you can translate it "word by word". "Gotos" don't exist in the most modern languages. You should translate algorithms to use the benefits of the destination language.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18863309/the-equivalent-of-a-goto-in-python

You will find all explanation regarding why there are no goto's in Python

Comment: Actually, the link I gave was already a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/438844/is-there-a-label-goto-in-python