# Python going back to another line of code

Tags: python

Is there a way for after multiple inputs down different paths, for it to continue at another line of code no matter what path has been followed?
example :

```
    a = raw_input("1 or 2")
if a == "1" :
    a = raw_input("3 or 4")
    if a == "3" :
        *line of code that makes the script progress at line #14*
    if a == "4" :
        *line of code that makes the script progress at line #14*
if a = "2" :
    a = raw_input("5 or 6")
    if a == "5" :
        *line of code that makes the script progress at line #14*
    if a == "6" :
        *line of code that makes the script progress at line #14*
print ("chocolate")
(^line #14^)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/438844/is-there-a-label-goto-in-python

Comment: [import goto](http://entrian.com/goto/)

Comment: I would argue that the need for this implies poor program design ... you may want to rethink your control flow

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is a **goto** statement. Fortunately*, Python *does not* provide this feature. You can try using functions instead:

```
def print_chocolate():
    print("chocolate")

if a == "1" :
    a = raw_input("3 or 4")
    if a == "3" or a == "4" :
        print_chocolate()

if a == "2" :
    a = raw_input("5 or 6")
    if a == "5" or a == "6":
        print_chocolate()
```

**Note:**

You can save some lines of code by using logical operators (`or`, `and`).

Comment: "Unfortunately" ---> "Fortunately"

Answer (score 0):

Wanting to use goto is often an indication to see if you can structure your code better: I agree with the [Joran Beasley's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22649167/python-going-back-to-another-line-of-code#comment34497120_22649167) that with good control structure you shouldn't need goto (many discussions on this see e.g. [goto still considered harmful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46586/goto-still-considered-harmful.)).

In my opinion, your program should reflect your intent and clearly divide responsibilities. I guess this is a toy example, but still there seem to be two things going on: getting and interpreting user input, and output. I think a clearer program, that avoids goto is as follows.

```
def UserInputDeservesChocolate():
    chocolate = False
    a = raw_input("1 or 2")
    if a == "1" :
        a = raw_input("3 or 4")
        chocolate = a == "3" or a == "4"
    if a == "2" :
        a = raw_input("5 or 6")
        chocolate = a == "5" or a == "6"
    return chocolate

if UserInputDeservesChocolate():
    print ("chocolate")
```