# GOTO Python 2.7.13

Tags: python, goto

How do I use/make a goto statement in python 2.7.13. Specifically, what I am trying to do is ask the user to put in an input of a *yes* or *no* statement.

If they type in *Yes* they will continue to there next line but if they answer *No* I want the user to return to a previous line.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a label/goto in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/438844/is-there-a-label-goto-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

A `GOTO` statement is a symptom of bad code design. Python is a structured language and lacks this statement, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/438869/1705337) if you want to implement a pseudo `GOTO` statement.

A better solution is to use better code design with loops or functions:

#### Loop

```py
while True:
    answer = input("Do you want to continue?")
    if answer == "yes":
        break
print("We are done here!")
```

#### Function

```py
def ask_question():
    answer = input("Do you want to continue?")
    if answer == "no":
        ask_question()

ask_question()
print("We are done here!")
```

Comment: This is a if  statement not goto.  There are times when goto are the only option