# how to work around go-to in python?

Tags: python, goto, squish

I've a scenario where I've called particular block of code after a set of actions. I used `go-to` and `label` in Python. It works as expected.

Is there any other better alternative for this?

This is Python code for automation using Squish-for-QT.

```
label .mylabel 

while (cond1):
        print("inside cond1")
        Function1(x,y,z)
else:
    if (object.exists("obj1")):
        Screen1 = waitForObject("obj1")
        print ("Inside Screen1")

        while (Screen1.visible):
            Function1(a,b,c)
        else:
            goto .mylabel
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a label/goto in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/438844/is-there-a-label-goto-in-python)

Comment: _"It works as expected."_ - It does? Python doesn't have native support for goto's. Are you using some library?

Comment: Yes it worked. I used the "entrian go-to" library. Now, I've edited the code to use the "while True" solution suggested by "wphicks"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this particular case, wrapping the whole thing in a `while True` will achieve the same behavior:

```
while True:
    while (cond1):
            print("inside cond1")
            Function1(x,y,z)
    else:
        if (object.exists("obj1")):
            Screen1 = waitForObject("obj1")
            print ("Inside Screen1")

            while (Screen1.visible):
                Function1(a,b,c)
        else:
            break
```

Checking this branch-by-branch:

If cond1 is met, we continually execute Function1(x, y, z)

Once cond1 is not met, we fall into else.

If obj1 exists, we wait for obj1, otherwise, we break out of the while True loop.

After waiting for obj1, we continue to run Function1(a,b,c) while Screen1 is visible, and then go back to the beginning of the while True loop (consistent with the original goto).

Answer (score 1):

You could define the code above into a function and use some basic recursion like so

```
def action():
    while (cond1):
        print("inside cond1")
        Function1(x,y,z)
    else:
        if (object.exists("obj1")):
            Screen1 = waitForObject("obj1")
            print ("Inside Screen1")

            while (Screen1.visible):
                Function1(a,b,c)
            else:
                action()
```

Generally using recursion is more common place. Hope this helps

Comment: This will eventually overflow the stack if it hits the recursive call too many times, and I think you may have gotten the indentation wrong on the last `else`.

Comment: The code in the question flows out of the loop if `object.exists("obj1")` tests false, and reenters the outer loop if `Screen1.visible` tests false. Your code has the opposite behavior.