# a Python version of batch-file's GOTO command?

Tags: python

I've looked all over Stackoverflow, for an answer to this question, but can't seem to find it. I am starting out in Python and I am attempting to make a simple quiz game. I want the player to be able to type the name of the menu they want to `goto`.

I have this so far:

```
print("Hello, and welcome to the Python Quiz.")
print("[START]")
print("[HELP]")
print("[ABOUT]")
print("[EXIT]")
menu = input("Type name of menu to navigate to corresponding menu. ")

if menu == "START":
    ...........
```

What comes next?

Comment: and 1s google search: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/438844/is-there-a-label-goto-in-python

Comment: Surely you would want to be calling functions instead of using labels. To my knowledge, batch is pretty much the only language where "don't use goto" isn't a thing.

Comment: @Julien, though it might be a similar question, it cannot be considered as a duplicate if the linked question does not have an accepted answer, especially considering the fact that the linked question was marked as off topic.

Comment: @GerhardBarnard second link is an exact dupe.

Comment: How this question could be even remotely related to the `batch-file` tag?  **`:(`**  -1

Comment: @Julien I was referring to the 1st link.

Comment: @Aacini Hence why I removed it..

Comment: @GerhardBarnard: Yes. I could did the same instead of post my comment, but my purpose was that the OP be aware about this point...

Comment: @Aacini. Yes i know. :)

Answer (score 0):

I would define each menu as what it should print like

```
def help():
  print(option1)
  print(option2)
  print(option3)
```

then you can just do something like

```
if menu == "HELP":
  help()
elif menu == "START":
  start()
```