# How to use the code in a loop after one part of the code is completed?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using python 3, and I want to know how to return the code to the second line`x = input ('Enter your first name here: ')`  after completing the if or elif conditions

I have searched other stack overflow answers but to no avail

```
print ("hello world")
x = input ('Enter your first name here: ')
if len(x) > 10:
    print ("You have a long name")
elif:
    print ("You have a short name")
```

Comment: What do you mean by return the code to the second line? Do you want to print the name after if-elif block?

Comment: Loops are covered in the very first part of the Python tutorial "First steps towards programming": https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#first-steps-towards-programming (in your case, if you want to return indefinitely until the user aborts the program, you can use a `while True:` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `elif` with `else`

The elif is short for else if. It allows us to check for multiple expressions. You aren't checking anything hence it should be replaced with else

Plus by doing that you fix a syntax error

```
    elif:
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

This is not a valid Python statement.

edit:

if you want to repeat the question askeed to the user use a while loop:

in your case:

```
while True:
    x = input ('Enter your first name here: ')
    if len(x) > 10:
        print ("You have a long name")
    else:
        print ("You have a short name")
```

This will work forever unless you kill it via a Task Manager or interrupt it using the keyboard.

Comment: this is not what OP has asked!

Comment: @taurus05 What exactly *did* OP ask? ‍♂️

Comment: @deceze, OP wants to jump to this line 2, `x = input ('Enter your first name here: ')`, after the if and elif conditions are done. This is similar to the behaviour of goto, which is not supported in python.

Comment: Updated @taurus05

Comment: @deceze, this is not a duplicate. The link that you've shared is about moving back to the first line of code. What if, there are 10 lines in the code and the pointer is to be moved on to the 4th line of the code, which doesn't require a loop?

Comment: @taurus05 I expect OP to be able to figure that out, once they know `while True`.

Comment: @deceze, seems fine then. If this is not what OP is expecting, marking it as duplicate won't make any sense.

Comment: @taurus05 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/438844/is-there-a-label-goto-in-python

Answer (score 0):

You can use loop statement to return the second check condition again. Please refer this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_while_loops.asp) for loops in python

for example of using while loop

```
answer = None
while True:
answer = raw_input("Do you like pie?")
if answer in ("yes", "no"): break
print "That is not a yes or a no"
```

it works like goto statement. you can use break or continue statement to stop or continue execution of loop.