# label/GOTO or similar function in python3

Tags: python, python-3.7, goto

I am self teaching myself python 3.8 I have some experience with BATCH which has a GOTO function. Is there a function in python that replicates it. I know there's other question about it .But none of them answers how a beginner can understand it.

For example :

```
try:
   age = int(input('input your age: '))
   print(age)
except ValueError:
   print('Enter a value')
```

Let's say I want to jump to the beginning whenever user enters something else than a number.

Comment: You very much need a more comprehensive tutorial than a Stack Overflow answer can provide. No, there is no GOTO, but that doesn't mean you can't do flow control. Additionally, read Dijkstra's GOTO Considered Harmful http://www.u.arizona.edu/~rubinson/copyright_violations/Go_To_Considered_Harmful.html

Comment: Put your code in a while loop.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a label/goto in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/438844/is-there-a-label-goto-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

You Can Use Loop Looks Like Below:

```
user_input = input ("Enter your Age")
con =True

while(con):
    user_input = input("Enter your Age")
    try:
        val = int(user_input)
        print("Input is an integer number. Number = ", val)
        con = False

    except ValueError:
        print("No.. input is not a number. It's a string")
        con = True
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer your immediate question, you can run an endless loop (`while True`: because `True` is always... `True`) and `break` out of it when you're happy with the answer:

```
while True:
    try:
       age = int(input('input your age: '))
       print(age)
       break
    except ValueError:
       print('Enter a value')
```

That is essentially the minimal answer without changing rest of your code.

There is no `goto` in Python. But you run a block of code as long as condition is met or you `break` out of the it: [`while`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#while).

You can see basic example and introduction in the [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#first-steps-towards-programming) and follow more on flow control in the [next chapter](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html).