# How to skip a fixed number of lines in a python code?

Tags: python, syntax

In a python code, how to *skip* a few lines of code?

For example, this is the code:

```py
if value == 10:
    <skip_the_next_seven_lines_of_code>
if value == 15:
    <skip_the_next_eight_lines_of_code>
#code continues...
```

Note that this can be done using a lot of workarounds, like putting the code in the `else` statement, but I want to avoid that as it would require a lot of `else`s as I have a lot of `if`s.
I am asking whether there is a function which is like:
`skiplines(7)`
Then the next 7 lines are skipped.

Also, this question has been downvoted many times, but I do not understand why. If there is no such way to accomplish this it can be answered in that way...

Comment: What do you mean by *skip a number of lines*? Using ```if...else```, you can skip a lot of lines

Comment: I have edited the question. Note that I want to specifically avoid that

Comment: So use `if value != 10:` and put the lines there. Then it won’t be in an else

Comment: Yes :). But this does not answer my question, as it does not `skip` lines...it is also just a workaround...

Comment: That’s exactly what it does. You make no sense

Comment: In that case, you should use classes and functions

Comment: @Sujay, can you provide an example?

Comment: _"Note that this can be done using a lot of workarounds, like putting the seven-lines-of-code in the else statement, but I want to avoid that."_ `if-else` is not a workaround. Why do you want to avoid *standard* Python syntax?

Comment: ```if...else```, all statements indented in it will be skipped. That is why they are called **control statements**

Comment: Is there a language (besides possibly Assembly; but even there it is in bytes - not lines, I think) that supports these `skip`s?

Comment: @AGN Lauguages with Go-to syntax would support that.

Comment: So, are you asking whether Python has `goto`? And why do you want to avoid `if-else`?

Comment: Sounds like a `goto`. Someone implemented [`goto` in Python](https://github.com/cdjc/goto).

Comment: @AGNGazer that is what I am asking. I want to avoid `if-else` because that would make a lot of repetitive `if-else`s if there are a lot of `if`s and then to make it less repeatitive, we would need nested `if-else`s which would make the code even complex to read (my opinion)

Comment: @CoolCoder BTW, I agree that this question does not have to be downvoted; Maybe it is not standard syntax on Python, but this does not necessarily mean the question is bad.  
Perhaps people are confused why "if-else" is seen as a workaround and to be avoided.  You could add an example with a lot of nested "if-else" and ask for approaches to simplify and improve the readability of the code.

Comment: I can't imagine using `goto` to _"improve the readability"_.

Comment: I downvoted because the problem to solve is not clear. If OP has messy code, show the messy code and ask if there is a better way. And then the code probably belongs on code review if it is working code that needs to be improved.

Comment: _"If there is no such way to accomplish this it can be answered in that way..."_ There is _a way to accomplish_ (or _achieve_) but you do not like it - see your comment to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can handle by the number of lines.
A closest I could think of is to define a function of the corresponding code block as below.

```py
value = 10  # or set other value

task = lambda: print("this is original task")

if value == 10:
    task = lambda: None

task()  # if value==10, this does nothing.
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the original answer to the original question (see question edits):

```
if value != 10:
    <some_seven_lines>
<the_rest_of_the_code>
```

The updated question shows a slightly more complicated pattern. Let's say something like this (I have to create an example since OP does not provide specific code/problem that he/she is trying to solve):

```
    a = 0  # some variable that lines of code will modify
    if value == 10:
        goto L1  # same as "skip next 7 lines"
    if value == 15:  # line 1 to "skip"
        goto L2      # line 2 to "skip"; same as "skip next 8 lines"
    a += 1           # line 3 (or 1 from second "if") to "skip"
    a += 10          # line 4 (or 2 from second "if") to "skip"
    a += 100         # line 5 (or 3 from second "if") to "skip"
    a += 1000        # line 6 (or 4 from second "if") to "skip"
    a += 10000       # line 7 (or 5 from second "if") to "skip"
L1: a += 100000      # line - (or 6 from second "if") to "skip"
    a += 1000000     # line - (or 7 from second "if") to "skip"
    a += 10000000    # line - (or 8 from second "if") to "skip"
L2: a += 100000000   # line 11 (or 13 from second "if")
```

This could be done in the following way:

```
a = 0

def f1(a):
    a += 1
    a += 10
    a += 100
    a += 1000
    a += 10000
    return a

def f2(a):
    a += 100000
    a += 1000000
    a += 10000000
    return a

if value == 10:
    a = f2(a)
elif value == 15:
    pass
else:  # or elif value != 15 and skip the branch above
    a = f1(a)
    a = f2(a)

a += 100000000
```

Of course, specific answer would depend on the question with a specific example, which, as of now, is missing.

Also, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/41768438/8033585

Comment: This *achieves* the same work I want to achieve...but it does not *skip* lines..

Comment: @AGN can you please add some description in your answer. like what you have do, what OP is doing wrong. why OP should follow your answer

Comment: @Xitiz _"why OP should follow your answer"_ Because it is achieving exactly what OP wanted to achieve, as OP admitted in the comment above: _"This achieves the same work I want to achieve..."_